# C++ overloaded function issue

Tags: c++, inheritance

Why does the compiler not find the base class function signature? Changing `foo( a1 )` to `B::foo( a1 )` works.

Code:

```
class A1 ;
class A2 ;

class B
{
public:
   void foo( A1* a1 ) { a1 = 0 ; }
} ;

class C : public B
{
public:
   void foo( A2* /*a2*/ )
   {
      A1* a1 = 0 ;
      foo( a1 ) ;
   }
} ;

int main()
{
   A2* a2 = 0 ;
   C c ;
   c.foo( a2 ) ;
   return 0 ;
}
```

Compiler error (VS2008):

```
error C2664: 'C::foo' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'A1 *' to 'A2 *'
Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast
```

Comment: Do you get that error on the last line of `C::foo` or `main`?

Comment: Error is at `foo( a1 )` in `C::foo()`.

Comment: It is called "name hiding". Read the FAQ: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/strange-inheritance.html#faq-23.9

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/411103/ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1480085/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The name `C::foo` *shadows* the name `B::foo`.  Once the compiler finds the matching `foo` in class C, it stops searching any further.

You can resolve your problem by adding:

```
using B::foo;
```

to the body of class C, or by renaming the function in class B.

Comment: Also, main is not allowed to be void.  It must return an int, by C++ standard.

Comment: You can also make the function virtual in class B.

Comment: My question now adheres to the C++ standard.

Comment: @ChrisInEdmonton:  Making the functions virtual won't resolve this problem because the two declarations of `foo` have different signatures.