# Why is does argument-dependent lookup for an overriden function work when called via a base class but not when called via a derived class?

Tags: c++

I'm having some trouble understanding in C++ the subtleties of argument-dependent lookup for member functions of class hierarchies.  In the following code, the correct version of `foo` is picked out by argument-dependent lookup if I call it through a base class reference.  But if I call it from a derived class object, compilers (I tried several) reject the code, saying that the call to `foo`is ambiguous.  What is the fundamental difference between the two cases that is driving this behaviour ?

```
struct Base
{ virtual void foo(int) = 0;
  virtual void foo(const char*) = 0;
};

struct Mid1 : virtual Base { void foo(int); };
struct Mid2 : virtual Base { void foo(const char*); };

struct Top : Mid1, Mid2 {};

int main()
{ Top t;
  Base &b = t;
  b.foo(1); //OK -  Mid1.foo is called
  t.foo(1); //error - ambiguous call to function
}
```

Comment: A note about terminology. This is not argument-dependent lookup. ADL applies to free functions only. What you call ADL is overload resolution, which happens after name lookup (including ADL).

Comment: The compiler doesn't know which one you want.  Use `t.Mid1::foo(1);`

Comment: Note that [the UN-accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58702133/16287) in the duplicate answers this "What is the fundamental difference" question.  The accepted answer does not.