# C++: rationale behind hiding rule

Tags: c++, language-design

What's the rationale behind the [hiding rule](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/strange-inheritance.html#faq-23.9) in C++?

```
class A { void f(int); }
class B : public A { void f(double); } // B::f(int) is hidden
```

- If it is a meaningful feature I think it should also be possible to hide functions without defining new functions with the same name: something like this:

  ```
   class B : public A { hide void f(double); }
  ```

but this is not possible.

- I don't think it simplifies compilers job, since compilers must anyway be able to *unhide* functions when you explicitly use the `using` directive:

  ```
   class B : public A { using A::f; void f(double); } // B::f(int) NOT hidden
  ```

So, how come there is a hiding rule?

Comment: While the decision was not based on easing the life of compiler writers, the argument that the compiler still needs to unhide is invalid. When the compiler parses the class with the using, it brings all the `A::f` into the in memory representation of the class. When it tries to resolve a call, it only needs to go back as far as needed until it finds the first occurrence of the identifier. There is no need to keep going back accross possibly multiple paths to bring all possible identifiers into scope. The same goes for the fact that a member method will hide a namespace level function...

Comment: AFAIK, *hiding without defining new functions* is possbile in C++11 via `=delete`.

Comment: There _is_ a mechanism for hiding base class functions. Use `class A : protected B { ... };` instead of `public`. Sorry for beating a dead horse.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's an hairy question, but apparently the idea is that this hiding feature helps avoiding subtle bugs when making changes to a base class (that could otherwise "steal" calls that before would have been handled by the derived class). Still a change in a base class can influence the result of compilation of derived classes so I don't think I understand 100% this explanation.

I agree that this topic is so frequently discussed that probably the hiding actually increases the amount of "surprises" in C++ programmers.

A detailed discussion about this issue can be found [here](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.c++.moderated/browse_thread/thread/eaff853f95675dfb/08451b3ef9b2c460)...

Comment: Yes, I have just spent 2 hours surprised by why won't the compiler see my function when the example on the internet works fine.

Answer (score 10):

i don't know the original rationale, but since hide or not hide are about equally bad choices wrt. to functions, i'm guessing the rationale is to have *uniform rules*: the same as for names defined in nested curly-braces scopes.

the hiding helps you in some ways.

adding a method to a base class will by default not affect overload resolution for a derived class.

and you do not run afoul of overload resolution by some mishap directing your call with say argument `false`, to a base class method with formal argument `void*`. such things.

cheers & hth.,

Comment: I'm baffled you're actually the only one who talked about consistency with hiding functions from others scopes! I still think it is mostly a matter of avoiding surprises.

Answer (score 8):

I'm sure I've seen this case offered by a C++ bigwig, not sure which:

```
struct Base {
    void f(const Base&);
};

struct Derived : Base {
    using Base::f;
    void f(double);
};

int main() {
    Derived d;
    d.f('a'); // calls Derived::f
}
```

Now, add `void f(int);` to `Base`, and the meaning of main changes - it calls `Base::f` because `int` is a better match for `char` - it's an integer promotion rather than a standard conversion.

It's not clear whether that change to the base would really be *intended* by the programmer to catch calls with `char`, so requiring `using` to be explicit means the default behavior is that the change doesn't affect the calling code. I believe it's a marginal call, but I think the committee decided that base classes in C++ were fragile enough as they are, without this too :-)

There's no need for a "hide" keyword because there's no comparable case for hiding "f" from the Base when it *isn't* overloaded in Derived.

Btw, I've chosen the types, and `char` is deliberately incongruous. You can get more subtle cases with `int` vs `unsigned int` rather than `int` vs `char`.

Answer (score 3):

Another reason for hiding base class's member function (with same name but different signatures) might be due to ambiguity caused by optional parameters. Consider the following example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

class A
{
public:
    int foo(int a, int b=0)
    {
        printf("in A : %d, %d\n", a, b);
    }
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    int foo(int a)
    {
        printf("in B : %d\n", a);
        foo(a); //B:foo(a) will be called unless we explicitly call A:foo(a)
        foo(a, 1); // compile error: no matching function for call to B:foo(int&, int)
    }
};


int main()
{
    B b;
    b.foo(10);
    return 0;
}
```

If the `foo` method in base class hadn't become hidden, it wouldn't be possible for compiler to decide whether `A::foo` should be called or `B::foo` since the following line matches both signatures:

```
foo(a);
```

Answer (score -2):

Probably, the reason is template specialization. I give you an example:

```
template <int D> struct A { void f() };

template <> struct A<1> { void f(int) };

template <int D>
struct B: A<D>
{
  void g() { this->f(); }
};
```

The template class B has a method `f()`, but until you don't create an instance of the class B you don't know the signature. So the call `this->f()` is anytime *"legal"*. Both GCC and CLang don't report error until you create the instance. But when you call the method `g()` on a `B<1>` instance they indicate the error. So the hiding rule keep simpler to check if your code is valid.

I report the last part of code used in my example.

```
int main (int argc, char const *argv[])
{
  B<0> b0; /* valid */
  B<1> b1; /* valid */

  b0.g(); /* valid */
  b1.g(); /* error: no matching function for call to ‘B<1>::f()’ */

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Except that, in your example, there is absolutely nothing in template class B that would hide the method f that is declared in template class A... The error does not come from the fact that f(void) is hidden in B<1> (why would it be more hidden in B<1> than in B<0> since there is no specialization). Your problem is *just* that f(void) is not declared at all in A<1> : there is nothing to hide.