# How does compiler implements inheritence?

Tags: c++, inheritance

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C++: rationale behind hiding rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4837399/c-rationale-behind-hiding-rule)

Suppose I have a code:

```
class  A
{       
    public:
    void f(int s) {}
};



class B:public A
{      
    public:
    void f() {}
};

int main()
{      B ob;
   ob.f(4);
}
```

Then in this case compiler generates an error that "no matching function for call to ‘B::f(int)'"
But class B has inherited A as public so B must have the function "void f(int s)". Dont know why compiler is generating error here?

Comment: You should not ask "how does the compiler" but "what are the rules in C++ that...".

Answer (score 5):

That is because `B` defines a different `f`, which *hides* the `f` inherited from `A`. If you want both available in `B` (which is likely), you must bring it into scope with a *using-declaration:*

```
class B : public A
{
  void f() {}
  using A::f;
};
```

This behaviour is specified in [class.member.loopkup], especially paragrah 4.

Comment: That is, if you want to overload `A::f(int)' with `B::f()`, you must do the above.

Comment: +1 "Hiding" is the correct term here.

Answer (score 3):

When you declare `void f()` in `B`, this *hides* the `void f(int)` inherited from `A`. You can bring it back into scope with `using`:

```
class B: public A
{      
public:
    void f() {}
    using A::f;
};
```

Comment: These two answers are very much the same.

Answer (score 0):

This is called Hiding - you can check the [C++ FAQ Entry](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/hiding-rule.html). It describes the problem and the solution.