# Hiding of all overloaded methods in base class

Tags: c++, inheritance

recently i came to know this - if a derived class redefines base class member method(s) then all the base class methods with same name become hidden in derived class.

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

class Base
{
public:
int fun()
{
    cout<<"Base::fun() called";
}
int fun(int i)
{
    cout<<"Base::fun(int i) called";
}
};

class Derived: public Base
{
public:
int fun() 
{
    cout<<"Derived::fun() called";
}
};

int main()
{
Derived d;
d.fun(5);  // Compiler Error
return 0;
}
```

Error : 
    In function 'int main()':
    Line 30: error: no matching function for call to 'Derived::fun(int)'
    compilation terminated due to -Wfatal-errors.

but just wanna know the reason behind it? why is it not calling fun(int i) method of Base Class since Derived class is derived from Base

Comment: Which a compiler error you got?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4837399/951890

Comment: @  vaughn : i went through the link provided, but im not so clear. thats why posted this question again :)

Comment: @UmalStack: that's fine, but how is your question different from that question?

Comment: @ vaughn : i just want to have a more clearer answer that i can understand :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fundamental reason is to make code more robust.

```
struct Base {
};

struct Derived : Base {
    void f(long);
    void g() { f(3); } // calls Derived::f
}
```

Now suppose `Base` is defined in a library, and you get an update to that library and the update changes the definition of `Base`:

```
struct Base {
    void f(int);
};
```

Now suppose that searches for overloaded functions didn't stop when a name was found. In that case, `Derived::g` would call `Base::f` instead of `Derived::f`, and your derived class would quietly do something completely different from what it did before, and different from what it was designed and documented to do.

Answer (score 2):

You've already discovered that derived-class overloads will shadow (prevent the visibility of) base-class methods by the same name but different parameters.  Let's just claim this was done for some historical or perceived safety reason, and look at a fix:

```
class Derived: public Base
{
public:
  using Base::fun; // expose the base-class method
  int fun() 
  {
    cout<<"Derived::fun() called";
  }
};
```