# Overriding Overloaded Functions in Inheritance

Tags: c++

Text book extract:

> Anytime we redefine an overloaded function name from the base class, all the other versions are automatically hidden in the derived class.

I get this. But, **what is the reasoning behind this**. Or is it like that's how they designed C++?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4837399/c-rationale-behind-hiding-rule

Comment: Hmmm...so, no answers?

Answer (score 1):

It's to avoid accidentally providing access to/calling base class methods you don't intend to call. If you explicitly want to ALSO provide the base class methods the language provides that syntax with `using Base::function_name;`. Alternately if the functions are orthogonal in functionality, don't name them the same thing.