# calling interface methods in c++

Tags: c++, pure-virtual

So basically, in this code I create interface (abstract class) and then derived from it.

```
struct IPrintable
{
    virtual void Print() = 0;
};

struct Base : public IPrintable
{
    void Print()
    {
        std::cout << "Print from Base\n";
    }
};

//And another class after that
struct A_Struct : public Base
{

};
```

After that in main function I create A_Struct and 3 pointer to it :

```
int main()
{
A_Struct myA;

IPrintable* Printp = &myA;
Base* Basep = &myA;
A_Struct* Ap = &myA;

//And of course we calling Print method
Printp->Print();
Basep->Print();
Ap->Print();

system("Pause");
return 0;
}
```

And everything is fine. BUT if we have need to add another case of Print just to A_Struct like so:

```
struct A_Struct : public Base
{
    void Print(int myI)
    {
        std::cout << "Print num : " << myI << " from A_Struct\n";
    }
};
```

The program will say "'A_Struct::Print': function does not take 0 arguments", which is mean that compiler can't find function Print().

We can fix this error by casting Ap pointer to IPrintable* like so:

```
((IPrintable*)Ap)->Print();
```

And everything will be fine again. But my question is: Why does this error even appear? Why it can't find overridden function by default?

Comment: There **must** be a duplicate for this question. One moment...

Comment: add `using Base::Print;` before `A_Struct::Print(int)`

Comment: btw your `IPrintable` should have a virtual destructor

Comment: I wasn't able to find _exact_ duplicates, but these are, at the very least, closely related to your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1628768/why-does-an-overridden-function-in-the-derived-class-hide-other-overloads-of-the https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4837399/c-rationale-behind-hiding-rule