# Can the keyword "using" in C++ be used with something except of "namespace"?

Tags: c++

Can the keyword **using** in C++ be used with something except of keyword **namespace**? 
If no -- so why can't we simply write "**namespace ...**"? If yes -- may you give some examples of its usage in "non-namespace" context, please?

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1896830/why-should-i-use-the-using-keyword-to-access-my-base-class-method

Comment: I have answered you, but note that the first link provided by [google search "using keyword C++"](https://www.google.es/search?q=using+keyword+C%2B%2B&oq=using+keyword+C%2B%2B&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l3j69i60.3481j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) is the reference page of cppreference.com about it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are multiple different uses for the keyword `using`:

1. You can declare that all names within a namespace don't need the namespace prefix with a *using directive*, e.g., `using namespace std`.
2. You can declare that a specific member of a namespace doesn't need a namespace prefix with a *using declaration*, e.g., `using std::vector`.
3. You can declare that member functions of a base class shall not be hidden in a derived class, e.g., `using B::f;` where `B` is a base class and `f` is a possibly overloaded member of this base class.
4. You can declare that a base class's constructors shall be inherited, e.g., `using B::B;`.
5. You can bind template arguments and give a name to template or use it to alias types, e.g., `template <typename T> using singleton = std::pair<int, T>;`.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can `using` a single name. For instance

```
using std::swap;
```

does a "using" only to `swap` from namespace `std`, while

```
using namespace std;
```

pulls in every name in std.

Comment: Also to bring names from a base class in a derived class.

Comment: Also instead of `typedef` for [type aliases](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias) since c++11 (`using identifier = type_name;`).

Comment: One is a "directive", the other is a "declaration", non?

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Its used to declare namespace members. For example:

```
namespace homebrew
{
   template<typename T>
   struct vector {};
}

int main()
{
    {
        using namespace std;
        vector<T> v; //Refers to std::vector
    }
    {
        using homebrew::vector;
        vector<T> v; //Refers to homebrew::vector
    }
}
```

Also is used to do the same with class members:

```
#include <iostream>
struct B {
    virtual void f(int) { std::cout << "B::f\n"; }
    void g(char)        { std::cout << "B::g\n"; }
    void h(int)         { std::cout << "B::h\n"; }
 protected:
    int m; // B::m is protected
    typedef int value_type;
};

struct D : B {
    using B::m; // D::m is public
    using B::value_type; // D::value_type is public

    using B::f;
    void f(int) { std::cout << "D::f\n"; } // D::f(int) overrides B::f(int)
    using B::g;
    void g(int) { std::cout << "D::g\n"; } // both g(int) and g(char) are visible
                                           // as members of D
    using B::h;
    void h(int) { std::cout << "D::h\n"; } // D::h(int) hides B::h(int)
};
```

Finally, its used since C++11 to define [type aliases](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias), template aliases included:

```
using vector_of_bool = std::vector<bool>;

template<typename T>
using vector_t = std::vector<T>;
```

The examples were extracted from the [cppreference.com documentation about `using` keyword](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/using).