# Overloaded function in derived class (C++)

Tags: c++

This is a very basic question, but my C++ skills are a bit rusty...

I have a base class that has a member function that takes 3 arguments, e.g.:

```
class MyBaseClass
{
public:
    int func(int a, char b, int c);
};
```

and a derived class that overloads that function with a 1-argument version., e.g:

```
class MyDerivedClass : public MyBaseClass
{
public:
    int func(float a);
};
```

When I try to call the function from the base class on an object of the derived class, like this:

```
MyDerivedClass d;
d.func(1, 'a', 0);
```

the compiler complains that `MyDerivedClass::func() does not take 3 arguments`. That is true, but shouldn't I be able to access the base class function through an object of the derived class?

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: See this thread? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1896830/why-should-i-use-the-using-keyword-to-access-my-base-class-method

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`MyDerivedClass::func` is hiding the name `MyBaseClass::func`. You can fix this with a `using` declaration:

```
class MyDerivedClass : public MyBaseClass
{
public:
    using MyBaseClass::func;
    int func(float a);
};
```

Comment: I knew it had to be something simple.  It's been a long time since I've dusted off my C++ hat.  I never saw the `using` keyword before - is that new?

Comment: @JeffLoughlin `using` has been around since the beginning. It can do more stuff in C++11, but the use shown above is old-school.

Comment: I was a C->C++ convert about 12 years ago, then back again about 3 years later, so I guess I just never had an occasion to learn about `using` during my brief C++ experience.  Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You probably intended to declare the method `MyBaseClass::func()` as **`virtual`**

But, if you really want to achieve

> when I try to call the function from the base class on an object of
>   the derived class, like this

then, you can try

```
MyDerivedClass d;
d.MyDerivedClass::func( 3.14f );
```

This compiles and works, but does not seem to be good design.

> the compiler complains that `MyDerivedClass::func()` does not take 3
>   arguments

That is indeed true, per your class definition, MyDerivedClass::func() takes only one argument.

Comment: That wouldn't change anything (except it might produce a helpful warning on gcc).

Answer (score 0):

Add "using Class::func;" in MyDerivedClass.

```
class MyDerivedClass : public MyBaseClass
    {
    public:
        using MyBaseClass::func;
        int func(float a);
    };
```