# C++: cannot define member function

Tags: c++, c++11

Could you please advise why I am getting the error in the code below?

```
error: cannot define member function ‘Test<int>::Printer::Print’ within ‘Test<int>’
```

I am using `gcc` version `8.1.1` and compile the code as `g++ -std=c++11`.

Although, if I move the definition of function `Print` under the definition of `struct Printer` (i.e. making it inline implicitly), the compiler does not produce any error.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

template <typename Type>
struct TestBase {

 struct Printer {
  template <typename T>
  void Print(const T& t) {
    std::cout << t << std::endl;
  }
 };

};

template <typename Type>
struct Test;

template<>
struct Test<int> : public TestBase<int> {

 struct Printer : public TestBase<int>::Printer {
  template <typename T>
  void Print(int i, const T& t);
 };

 template <typename T>
 void Printer::Print(int i, const T& t) {
  std::cout << i << t << std::endl;
 }

};

int main() {
  Test<int> t;
}
```

**UPDATE**:

Brian pointed out the exact reason why it is the case: "... A member function definition that appears outside of the class definition shall appear in a namespace scope enclosing the class definition..."

Brian not only answered the main question that started this topic but also an additional question that I asked in the comment to the accepted answer of him.

Comment: Read the error message carefully.  The compiler is telling you the truth.  If you want to know why, it's because that's specified by the C++ standard.

Comment: I think I understand the compiler's message but I don't understand which rule is violated. Could you please help me to point that out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[class.mfct]/1, emphasis mine:

> ... A member function definition that appears outside of the class definition **shall appear in a namespace scope** enclosing the class definition. ...

An enclosing *class* scope is thus not an allowed location for the definition.

Comment: Brian, thank you very much for such a prompt and precise answer. I have a suspicion that this might not be the end of a story. Let's move the member function `Print` definition inside the `struct Printer` definition and change the `main` function as `Test<int>::Printer p; p.Print(3);`. I'll start getting the `no matching function for call to` error message. Is it somehow related to your answer? Is it because `void Print(const T& t)` is defined outside of the class definition?

Comment: @TruLa This is because `Test::Printer::Print` takes two arguments and it *hides* `TestBase::Printer::Print`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1896830/why-should-i-use-the-using-keyword-to-access-my-base-class-method