# statemachine using variadic template overloading

Tags: c++, variadic-templates

I am trying to build a statemachine in C++ using variadic templates.

```
class Event {};

template<typename... TEvents>
class StateMachineActionHandler
{
public:
    void action() = delete;
};

template<typename TEvent, typename... TEventRest>
class StateMachineActionHandler<TEvent, TEventRest...> : public StateMachineActionHandler<TEventRest...>
{
public:
    virtual void action(const TEvent& event)
    {
        std::cout << "default" << std::endl;
    }
    using StateMachineActionHandler<TEventRest...>::action;
};

template <class ...TEvents>
class State : public StateMachineActionHandler<TEvents...>
{
public:
    virtual void enterAction() = 0;
    virtual void exitAction() = 0;
};


template <class ...TStates>
class StateMachine
{
public:
    StateMachine()
    {
        m_cur = std::get<0>(m_states);
        std::visit([](auto state){state.enterAction();}, m_cur);
    }

    virtual ~StateMachine() = default;

    template<typename TEvent>
    void handleEvent(const TEvent& event)
    {
        std::visit([&event] (auto state){ state.action(event);}, m_cur);
    }

private:
    std::tuple<TStates...> m_states;
    std::variant<TStates...> m_cur;
};
```

Then I create a class that implements this statemachine. However for `StateA` I do not override the function `void action(const EventB& event)`, since I want it to have the empty default implementation that is provided in the templates.

```
class EventA : public Event {};
class EventB : public Event {};

class StateA : public State<EventA, EventB>
{
public:
    void action(const EventA& event) override { std::cout << "new A A" << std::endl;}

    void enterAction() override {std::cout << "enter A" << std::endl; }
    void exitAction() override {std::cout << "exit A" << std::endl; }
};

class StateB : public State<EventA, EventB>
{
public:
    void action(const EventA& event) override { std::cout << "new B A" << std::endl;}
    void action(const EventB& event) override { std::cout << "new B B" << std::endl;}

    void enterAction() override {std::cout << "enter B" << std::endl; }
    void exitAction() override {std::cout << "exit B" << std::endl; }
};

class StateC : public State<EventA, EventB>
{
public:
    void action(const EventA& event) override { std::cout << "new C A" << std::endl;}
    void action(const EventB& event) override { std::cout << "new C B" << std::endl;}

    void enterAction() override {std::cout << "enter C" << std::endl; }
    void exitAction() override {std::cout << "exit C" << std::endl; }
};

class StateMachineTest : public StateMachine<StateA, StateB, StateC>
{
};
```

Now if I use this class I get an compilation error:

```
int main()
{
    StateMachineTest testSM;
    EventB eventB;
    testSM.handleEvent(eventB);
}
```

`error: cannot convert ‘const EventB’ to ‘const EventA&’`

Why does it not see the empty default implementation?

Comment: where is the variable `eventB` defined?

Comment: Forgot to copy that into the example. I have edited the 'main' fuction

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `using`-declaration to introduce the default implementation into the derived class definition

```
class StateA : public State<EventA, EventB>
{
public:
    using State<EventA, EventB>::action;
    void action(const EventA& event) override { std::cout << "new A A" << std::endl;}

    void enterAction() override {std::cout << "enter A" << std::endl; }
    void exitAction() override {std::cout << "exit A" << std::endl; }
};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/37jMPc15h)

Comment: Indeed, that works! Could you elaborate a bit more why it works? I seem to not understand how the `using` works. And why does it find the default when I comment out the `void action(const EventA& event) override ` in `StateA`? (without the extra using you propose, that is)

Comment: @Frank [Why should I use the "using" keyword to access my base class method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1896830/why-should-i-use-the-using-keyword-to-access-my-base-class-method)