# Why can't overridden virtual method see overloaded base classes version without explicit scoping?

Tags: c++, inheritance, overloading

I don't understand why the compiler doesn't like this, here is and example of the problem:

```
class A
{
public:
    virtual void Expand() { }
    virtual void Expand(bool flag) { }
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    virtual void Expand() {
        A::Expand(true);
        Expand(true);
    }
};
```

When I try to compile this the `A::Expand(true);` compiles fine, but the non scoped `Expand(true);` gets this compiler error:

'B::Expand' : function does not take 1 arguments

Comment: The best I can tell is that method hiding exists to prevent a programmer from thinking they are are using an overloaded version of a base classes method.  But it seems like a bad thing to me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ override/overload problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1484641/c-override-overload-problem)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because besides overriding the base `Expand()`, you're also **hiding** the base `Expand(bool)`.

When you introduce a member function in a derived class with the same name as a method from the base class, all base class methods with that name are hidden in the derived class.

You can fix this by either qualifying (as you have) or with the `using` directive:

```
class B : public A
{
public:
    using A::Expand;
    virtual void Expand() {
        A::Expand(true);
        Expand(true);
    }
};
```

Comment: What is the hiding rule that makes it not visible?

Comment: @Solx the fact that they have the same name.

Comment: Meta Question: How do I decide which answer to accept, both are acceptable, given that I guess I should accept the first answer supplied.

Comment: @Solx it has nothing to do with which one was first. A great answer might show up in a week, and if it's better, accept that one.

Comment: @Solx: You are supposed to accept an answer which helps you solve the problem you posted in best possible way.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need `virtual` methods for that behaviour. Methods in a derived class **hide** methods with the same name in the base class. So if you have any function named `Expand` in your derived class (even if it is an override of a virtual method from the base class), none of the base classes methods with the same name are visible, regardless of their signature.

You can make the base classes methods visible with `using`. For that you would add `using A::Expand;` to the definition of `B`:

```
class B : public A
{
public:
    using A::Expand;  
    virtual void Expand() { Expand(true); }
};
```

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: What are you trying to say? Your original answer wasn't much longer then mine. From my point of view you hadn't written the part about using when I added it to my answer either (of course that might be lack of reload on my part). Its not like there are lots of possible answers for this question...