# Inheritance mucking up polymorphism in C++?

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism

Perhaps my knowledge of inheritance and polymorphism isn't what I thought it was.  Can anyone shed some light?

Setup (trivialization of problem):

```
class X {
};

class Y {
};

class Base {
  public:
    void f( X* ) {}
};

class Child: public Base {
  public:
    void f( Y* ) {}
};
```

Question: This should work, right?

```
int main( void ) {
  X* x = new X();
  Y* y = new Y();
  Child* c = new Child();
  c->f( x );
  c->f( y );
  return 0;
}
```

I get errors (GCC 4.4) to the tune of:

```
`no matching function for call to 'Child::f(X*&)'`
`note: candidates are: void Child::f(Y*)`
```

Comment: Name hiding. This question gets asked like 3 times a day. See the FAQ http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/strange-inheritance.html#faq-23.9

Comment: Did you mean for your two classes to be called A and B?

Comment: Perhaps I'm misreading, but are you sure that the arguments to f should be A and B?

Comment: His error message shows that he has no `A` and `B` in his real code. It is just a typo. I corrected the source.

Comment: Thanks, @AndreyT - I had A, B, C, and D originally but it was too confusing.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does an overridden function in the derived class hide other overloads of the base class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1628768/why-does-an-overridden-function-in-the-derived-class-hide-other-overloads-of-the)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `virtual` keyword will not help you here.

Your base class `Base::f` is being hidden by your derived type.  You need to do the following:

```
class Child: public Base {
  public:
    using Base::f;
    void f( Y* ) {}
};
```

[Parashift goes into more detail](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/strange-inheritance.html#faq-23.9).

Comment: Okay, I didn't know you could do 'using' in a class like that - thanks.

At any rate, I'm well familiar with the concept of name hiding - but is it really **ONLY** based upon function name, and not the entire signature?

Comment: Yes, the look-up by name happens before overload resolution, thus `Base::f` isn't considered for overloads without pulling them in explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

Your derived class' `f()` *hides* the base class' `f()`. You can prevent this by explicitly bringing `Base::f()` into the derived class' scope:

```
class Child: public Base {
  public:
    using Base::f;
    void f( Y* ) {}
};
```

Answer (score 0):

It was already answered at:

[Why does an overridden function in the derived class hide other overloads of the base class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1628768/why-does-an-overridden-function-in-the-derived-class-hide-other-overloads-of-the)

When you declare a method on a derived class, it hides any method with the same name from the base class.