# C++ : Multiple inheritance with polymorphism

Tags: c++, polymorphism, hierarchy, multiple-inheritance

(pardon the noob question in advance)

I have 4 classes:

```
class Person {};
class Student : public Person {};
class Employee : public Person {};
class StudentEmployee : public Student, public Employee {};
```

Essentially `Person` is the base class, which are directly subclassed by both `Student` and `Employee`. `StudentEmployee` employs multiple inheritance to subclass both `Student` and `Employee`.

```
Person pat = Person("Pat");
Student sam = Student("Sam");
Employee em = Employee("Emily");
StudentEmployee sen = StudentEmployee("Sienna");


Person ppl[3] = {pat, sam, em};
//compile time error: ambiguous base class
//Person ppl[4] = {pat, sam, em, sen};
```

When I use an array of `Person`, the base class, I can put `Person` and all of its subclasses inside this array. Except for `StudentEmployee`, given the reason ambiguous base class.

Given that `StudentEmployee` is guaranteed to have all the methods and attributes of `Person`, is `StudentEmployee` considered a subclass of Person?

- If so, Why does the compiler not allow me to assign an object to a variable of the type of its superclass?
- If not, why not; and what would be the proper way to accomplish this?

Cheers

---

EDIT: Preemptively, this question is NOT the same as either of the following:
[polymorphism relates inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2423231/polymorphism-relates-inheritance)
[Inheritance mucking up polymorphism in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1889996/inheritance-mucking-up-polymorphism-in-c)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`StudentEmployee` certainly is a subclass of `Person`. The problem is it is so *twice*: It indirectly inherits `Person` twice (once through `Student` and once through `Employee`) and that's why you get the "ambiguous base class" error. To make sure `StudentEmployee` only inherits `Person` once, you have to use *virtual inheritance*, like so:

```
class Person {};
class Student : public virtual Person {};
class Employee : public virtual Person {};
class StudentEmployee : public Student, public Employee {};
```

This will fix your error.

There is another big problem with your code, though, and it's called *[slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-the-slicing-problem-in-c)*.

When you do this:

```
Person ppl[3] = {pat, sam, em};
```

An array of three `Person` objects will be created but those objects will be copy constructed using the implicitly defined copy constructor of the `Person` class. Now, the problem with this is that the objects in your array will be just `Person` objects and not objects of the subclasses you want them to be.

To fix this, you'll have to make an array of pointers to `Person` objects, like this:

```
Person* ppl[] = {new Person("Pat"), new Student("Sam"),
                 new Employee("Emily"), new StudentEmployee("Sienna")};
```

or

```
Person* ppl[] = {&pat, &sam, &em, &sen};
```

Comment: But, obviously, calling new like that will almost certainly lead to a memory leak

Comment: +1 for the slicing.  And just in case bguiz didn't already know, this could also be Person* ppl[] = { &pat, &sam, &em, &sen }; - there is a slight difference in the memory management of these two options.

Comment: @Michael: Thanks, added that to my answer.

Comment: @Michael: well spotted :) raw pointer indicates that the memory is owned somewhere else.

Comment: +1 and switch checkmark to @Job : For pointing out the additional slicing problem - you've pre-empted the next thing that had me buggered!

Comment: @Job: I just mention that because the OP is clearly not too familiar with C++ and manually managing memory in a pointer array can be confusing. I probably worded it too harshly.

Comment: @bguiz- this talk about memory is to indicate that at the end of the application you'll want to remember to `for (int i = 0; i < (sizeof(ppl)/sizeof(ppl[0])); ++i) delete ppl[i];`

Comment: There's another way to avoid copy by initialising objects as pointers:

`Person *pat = Person("Pat");
Student *sam = Student("Sam");
Employee *em = Employee("Emily");
StudentEmployee *sen = StudentEmployee("Sienna");

Person *arr [] = {pat, sam, em, sen};`

Answer (score 3):

There are two equally possible paths from an object of type `StudentEmployee` to be a `Person`.

You need to use the keyword `virtual` for both `Student` and `Employee` classes. See [FAQ 25.8](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/multiple-inheritance.html#faq-25.8) In fact go through that entire section.

Comment: Thank you, that article hit the nail on the head!