# Java UML Student Worker project multiple inheritance

Tags: uml, diagram, class-diagram

There's an exercise I have which requires us to provide a UML Diagram for the following:

- A Person class (Abstract)
- Student (name, surname, school, grades)
- Worker (name, surname, salary) extends Person

A student can be a worker. A worker can also be a student. How would I achieve this?

This is my solution, but I understand that it's not efficient:

[image]

Comment: What is your idea so far?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1RhKAAS9ONkbzxZiZ4RCjxUaGomdOf18V

Comment: Please edit your question and include your approach instead of linking to clouds. Thank you!

Comment: I guess that _A student can be a worker. A worker can also be a student._  does not make sense. It implies mutual inheritance which is not possible.

Comment: It is not possible in Java, but in C++ it is… This is a question independent from a specific programming language, at least the tags just say uml, diagram and class-diagram.

Comment: In the title i wrote "java"

Comment: OK, I have seen that, will edit my answer soon

Comment: @deHaar I don't believe in C++ (correct me if I'm wrong) that you can have mutual inheritance, where A is both a superclass and subclass of B, and vice versa. I believe that you are confusing that with multiple inheritance, which is of course possible in C++ and is, as you say, language-specific.

Comment: @BobRodes Sorry for not being clear enough. You are right, of course... Mutual inheritance is not possible in any of the programming languages I know (OK, not that many, admittedly). My comment was about multiple inheritance (available in C++, not available in Java, not really sure about C#).

Comment: I'm surprised nobody mentioned the usage of the party-partyrole pattern. A person **is** not a worker, he plays the **role** of a worker, and the **role** of a student. Student and person are then subtypes of PartyRole, and a person is a subtype of Party.

Comment: @deHaar Not available in C# either, FYI. If I were more cynical than I am, I would say that C# was yet another attempt by Microsoft to create a proprietary version of an open standard, in this case Java. :)

Answer (score 2):

A possible solution would be the following:
[image]

This solution adds an extra class for the case of a student being a worker the same time.

**First Update**

The following image shows how `StudentWorker` may inherit from `Worker` and `Student`, though this might not be possible in every programming language and might as well lead to the *Diamond Problem*.

[image]

**Second Update**

This solution only makes use of implementing interfaces:

[image]

Please note that you still need 3 classes. `Student` and `Worker` implement two interfaces each, the `StudentWorker` implements all three interfaces. That makes all three classes a `Person` as well as a `Student` an `IStudent`, a `Worker` an `IWorker` and a `StudentWorker` an `IStudent` and an `IWorker`. I hope this helps or gives you an idea on how to create your individual solution.

Comment: But studentworker should be inheredit attribute and methods both from student and worker. In this solution studentworker is a third class indipendent from student and worker.
Edit: in this case you do not respect the poliformism.

Comment: Basically you end up in the same answer as @Ouissal.

Comment: Basically you are right, but my answer directly anwers the question instead of giving general advice on how to design UML.

Comment: In Java language that is not possible because studentworker inheredit from two classes. Am i wrong?

Comment: You are right, it is not possible in Java. Why haven't you tagged your question with an additional Java-tag? In C++, you can do *diamond* inheritance.

Answer (score 1):

Student and worker will both be a subclass of the class Person.
Person will have the common attributes which are common (name and surname).
Student will have school grades and worker will have salary.

This is how you can represent inheritance in UML :

[image]

You have a superclass, and your derived classes.
Since your superclass is abstract, it will have methods that are declared without an implementation, you'll implement them in your classes Student and Worker (if you have to).

If you have another class student-worker, it will inherit from both student and worker. So it will be something like this :

[image]

A is your abstract class Person, B and C are Student and Worker respectively, while D is StudentWorker.
StudentWorker will inherit the attributes of both Student and Worker.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1RhKAAS9ONkbzxZiZ4RCjxUaGomdOf18V
This is my idea. But studenteoperaio (studentworker) does not take attributes "salary" and "school grades" (in italian salario and voti)

Comment: I can't see that file, I don't have read access.
Student-worker will inherit from both classes student and worker, see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3541110/c-multiple-inheritance-with-polymorphism

Comment: Now can you see the file?

Comment: @Ouissal Good answer, though more general than mine. You really know the difference between learning and writing off and you want the questioner to be a learner.

Comment: Thank you @deHaar

Comment: @AlbertoMorreale No I can't see it, but I've edited my answer, I guess that's what you've meant

Comment: But D (StudentWorker) it is a class that extends two classes (student, worker) and this is not possibile in java. I thought to use interfaces but i manage to arrive to the solution.

Comment: Yes Java doesn't support multiple inheritance, if you're using Java then you can use interfaces instead, see this example : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-and-multiple-inheritance/

Comment: Multiple inheritance is evil per se and I'd never model anything in that direction. The requirement as it's written is plain nonsense and needs to be interrogated. A recursive inheritance (A inh. B and B inh. A) is wrong. So your solution is technically correct, but from a reality view it's plain nonsense.

Answer (score 0):

This may or may not be an answer to your exercise. If I got these requirements in the real world, I would refactor them. (Of course, in the real world, I would have a lot of questions about further refinements and details as well.) The real-world situation is (we may presume) that we are dealing with persons who always have a name and surname. Since the names and surnames don't change (we may also presume) when person is specialized into subclasses, there is no reason to provide a means to implement them differently in subclasses. Therefore there is no reason to make the person class abstract, since that's why you make abstract classes.

This is also a situation where aggregation (one class "has" other classes) makes more sense than inheritance (a subclass "is" a superclass). So I would restructure the requirements this way:

Person: Name, Surname
Student: School, Grades
Worker: Salary

Person class may "have" zero to one Student classes. Person class may "have" zero to one Worker classes.

There is also the implication, by requiring Person to be abstract, that a person must be either a student, a worker, or both. This can be specified by an `or`  constraint between the two classes.

Here's a diagram:

[image]

Person class has an aggregate relationship with both student and worker classes. One person class may have zero to one student classes. One person class may also have zero to one worker classes. The `{or}` constraint further specifies that there must be one of either student or worker, or one of each.