# How to assign / retrieve base class?

Tags: c++, inheritance

Suppose I have:

```
class Foo {
  ...
};
class Bar : public Foo {
  ...
};
Foo foo;
Bar bar;
```

Is there anyway to do the following:

```
foo_part_of_bar(bar) = foo;

foo = foo_part_of_bar(bar);
```

?

Thanks!

Comment: Where's the base class? I can only see 2 unrelated classes.

Comment: Did you mean `class Bar : public Foo`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you meant `class Bar : public Foo`, the following should work.

For `foo_part_of_bar(bar) = foo;`

```
*(static_cast<Foo *>(&bar)) = foo;
```

For `foo = foo_part_of_bar(bar);`

```
foo = bar;
```

Comment: Why not `static_cast<Foo&>(bar)` ?

Comment: This is assuming Foo has the default assignment operator / copy ctor. If both call virtual functions on the source then I don't think it's possible to copy the Foo part of bar to another Foo.

Comment: This answer ignores that the fields of `Bar` may be laid out in the padding of `Foo`.  I don't think there's a safe way to do what the OP wants.

Answer (score 4):

Apparently, you mean that `Bar` is a descendant of `Foo` in class hierarchy...

In that case to do the first part can be done in two different ways

```
// foo_part_of_bar(bar) = foo;
bar.Foo::operator =(foo);
(Foo &) bar = foo; // or use a C++-style cast
```

(The latter might misbehave in the exotic case when the corresponding `operator =` is declared virtual and overriden in `Bar`. But that's, as I said, exotic.)

To do the second part you don't really need to make any special efforts

```
// foo = foo_part_of_bar(bar);
foo = bar;
// This is called slicing
```

Both have very limited use in some very special contexts. I wonder what you need it for...

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>

struct Foo {
    Foo& operator=(const Foo&)
    {
        std::cout << "Foo::operator=\n";
        return *this;
    }
};
struct Bar : public Foo {
    Bar& operator=(const Bar&)
    {
        std::cout << "Bar::operator=\n";
        return *this;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Foo foo;
    Bar bar;

    Foo& foobar = bar;
    foobar = foo;

    foo = bar;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From here: [C++ How come I can't assign a base class to a child class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2241835/c-how-come-i-cant-assign-a-base-class-to-a-child-class/2246604#2246604)

For foo_part_of_bar(bar) = foo; :

```
bar.Foo::operator=(foo);
```

and for foo = foo_part_of_bar(bar);

```
foo = bar;
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a reference to the base class and then you can do anything you want with it, not just assign to it.

```
    class Base {
        Base& operator=(const Base& other);
    };

    Base meow();

    class Derived : public Base {
        void woof()
        {
            Base& baseRef = *this;
            baseRef = meow();
        }
    };
```