# Using this in a seperate class methods crashes the program

Tags: c++14, c++17, opencascade

I am having a challenge calling methods from a direct parent Base class but I can call methods in the Base class 's parent with ease. To clarify what I mean here is the code:

First the structure of the opencascade library classes:

```
class TopoDS_Shape 
{
public:
   //..... a lot of methods like Closed(), Oriantable(), etc
};

class TopoDS_Face : public TopoDS_Shape
{
   TopoDS_Face(); // implementation is like TopoDS_Face::TopoDS_Face(){}
}
```

In my code there are two types of topological faces Plane faces (ModelFace class) and NON-Planar faces (ModelBend class). These two faces share 6 attributes defined in the MFace class but only the ModelBend class has additional attributes of its own so I designed the system as follows

MFace class:

```
class MFace : public TopoDS_Face 
{
 FaceID mFaceID;
 PlaneType mPlaneType;
 FaceType mFaceType;
 gp_Pnt mFaceNormal;

 public:
  void ModelFace::extractEdges()
  {
    for (TopExp_Explorer edgeEx((*this), TopAbs_EDGE); edgeEx.More(); edgeEx.Next())
    {
      TopoDS_Edge edge = TopoDS::Edge(edgeEx.Current());
      ModelEdge edgex(edge);

      addEdge(edgex);
    }
  }

  // Setters and getters

  // The OpenCascade Lib has a non-template method similar to this for converting a  
  // TopoDS_Shape to a face/edge/vertex/wire
  template<typename T>
  static T& toFace(TopoDS_Face& shape)
  {
    return *(T*) &shape;
   }
};
```

ModelFace class:

```
 class ModelFace : public MFace
 {
   ModelFace(); // implementation is like ModelFace::ModelFace(){}

   void ModelFace::init(FaceID faceID) // WORKS LIKE A CHARM!!!
   { 
     setFaceId(faceID);

     std::cout << "ID : " << getFaceId() << '\n';

     if (Closed()) {
      std::cout << "Orr : " << Orientable() << '\n';
     }
   }

 };
```

ModelBend class:

```
class ModelBend : public MFace
 {
   // Bend attributes : angles, radius, etc
   ModelBend(); // implementation is like ModelBend::ModelBend(){}

   // Setters and getters
   // methods for computations

};
```

Usage : There is a Model class that represents a CAD model and stores all its topological ModelFace/ModelBend data. This class gets topological data in the form of a TopoDS_Shape and classifies it in the `assignAttributes()` as shown below :

```
  void Model::assignFaceAttributes(const FaceID faceID, TopoDS_Shape& aShape)
  {
    // TODO : set the face attributes
    TopoDS_Face pTopoDSFace = TopoDS::Face(aShape);
    Standard_Real curvature = computeCurvature(pTopoDSFace);

    if (curvature == 0.0){

      std::cout << "Face" << '\n';

      // Convert TopoDS_Face to ModelFace
      ModelFace& pModelFace = MFace::toFace<ModelFace>(pTopoDSFace);

      // This code work well : calls Orientable() in the TopoDS_Shape class
      std::cout << "Orientable? : " << pModelFace.Orientable() << '\n';

      // Works well
      pModelFace.init(faceID);

      // **PROGRAM CRASHES HERE!!!!!!!!!!!!!!**
      pModelFace.extractEdges();

      //...

    } else {
      // .....
      std::cout << "Bend" << '\n';

      // Convert TopoDS_Face to ModelBend
      ModelBend& pModelFace = MFace::toFace<ModelBend>(pTopoDSFace);

      //...
    }

    addFace(&pModelFace);

  }
```

When I run the program it crashes on the call to `pModelFace.extractEdges()` in the `assignAttributes()` but when I copy the for loop in the `extractEdges()` method into the `init()` method it works fine.

My OOD/OOP ain't that good. May you please help me solve the problem and the why's of this behaviour. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a duplicate to your own other question:
[Assigning a TopoDS_Face object to its child object compiles with no errors but I have 3 valgrind errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55852277/assigning-a-topods-face-object-to-its-child-object-compiles-with-no-errors-but-i/60216012#60216012)

`TopoDS_Shape` has **no virtual methods** (including no virtual destructor) and managed within OCCT **by copy** (e.g. not dynamically allocated). Adding class fields like you do in `MFace` will work only if you store object exactly like `MFace` - otherwise you are just casting a smaller in memory object `TopoDS_Shape` to a larger `MFace` leading to reading/writing to an uninitialized memory and crash.

The main difference between your `MFace` and `TopoDS_Face` is that `TopoDS_Face` defines **NO new class fields** nor virtual methods, which allows aliasing `TopoDS_Shape` to `TopoDS_Face` without side effects.

For instance:

```cpp
void parseMFace (TopoDS_Shape& theFace)
{
  MFace* anMFace = (MFace* )&theFace;
  anMFace->doSomething();
}

int main()
{
  MFace anMFace;
  parseMFace (anMFace); // unsafe, but should work
  TopoDS_Face aTFace;
  parseMFace (aTFace); // will crash
  TopoDS_Compound aComp;
  BRep_Builder().MakeCompound (aComp);
  BRep_Builder().Add (aComp, anMFace); // here MFace will be truncated to TopoDS_Shape
  for (TopoDS_Iterator aFaceIter (aComp); aFaceIter.More(); aFaceIter.Next()
  {
    TopoDS_Face& aTFace2 = TopoDS::Face (aFaceIter.Value());
    parseMFace (aTFace2); // will crash, because TopoDS_Compound does not store MFace 
  }
  std::vector<MFace> anMFaces;
  anMFaces.push_back (anMFace);
  parseMFace (anMFaces[0]); // OK, but unsafe
}
```

Comment: OK I see. So do I have to create say MFace class without inheritance and then extract all TopoDS_Face properties that I need and assign them to its children such that they exist without any association with the OCCT objects? I want to have a ModelFace/ModelBend face that isnt a copy of TopoDS_Face  or have an object that I can use for geometric computations without having to (a) store a TopoDS_Face object as a MFace class member variable or (b) redesign some computing methods like computeCurvature that will work on MFace child objects and not TopoDS_Face objects(as in the current design).

Comment: Storing a copy of TopoDS_Face as a class field of MFace will not cause any performance problems (if it is what you are afraid of) - TopoDS_Shape objects are a special smart-pointer objects, so that underlying geometry/children are not duplicated on making TopoDS_Shape copy, only location and orientation flags.
Otherwise, consider using external maps for storing per-shape information.