# Why do I get no matching function when I inherit this function

Tags: c++, inheritance

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [overloaded functions are hidden in derived class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3202234/overloaded-functions-are-hidden-in-derived-class)

I have Class A and Class B (subclass of A)

Class A has function

```
virtual void foo(int, int);
virtual void foo(int, int, int);
```

When I try to do

Class B with function

```
virtual void foo(int, int);
```

When I try to call foo(int, int, int) with the class the compiler won't let me because it says

```
no matching function for foo(int,int,int)
candidate is foo(int,int);
```

Comment: Or another potential dupe is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4146499/why-does-a-virtual-function-get-hidden. Not sure whether the questioner expects that the functions being virtual is important, but it makes no difference.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The reason why has to do with the way C++ does name lookup and overload resolution.  C++ will start at the expression type and lookup upwards until it finds a member matching the specified name.  It will then only consider overloads of the member with that name in the discovered type.  Hence in this scenario it only considers `foo` methods declared in `B` and hence fails to find the overload.

The easiest remedy is to add `using A::foo` into `class B` to force the compiler to consider those overloads as well.

```
class B : public A {
  using A::foo;
  virtual void foo(int, int);  
};
```

Answer (score 3):

The override in class B hides the methods of class A with the same name.  (Do you have compiler warnings on?  Most compilers warn about hidden virtual methods.)

To avoid this, add

```
using A::foo;
```

to class B (in whatever `public`/`protected`/`private` section is appropriate).

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
B b;
b.A::foo(1,2,3);
```

for example.