# Unable to use method of base class

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, methods

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [overloaded functions are hidden in derived class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3202234/overloaded-functions-are-hidden-in-derived-class)

It seems that I cannot directly use methods from a base class in a derived class if they are overloaded in both the base class and the derived class in C++. The following code produces the error `no matching function for call to ‘Derived::getTwo()’`.

```
class Base {
public:
    int getTwo() {
        return 2;
    }
    int getTwo(int, int) {
        return 2;
    }
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
    int getValue() {
        // no matching function for call to ‘Derived::getTwo()’
        return getTwo();
    }
    int getTwo(int) {
        return 2;
    }
};
```

If I change `return getTwo();` to `return ((Base*) this)->getTwo()`, it works, but that looks ugly to me. How can I fix this?

P.S. I use g++ 4.7 with option std=gnu++c11, if that matters.

Comment: This will definitely be closed as a duplicate, but in the meantime, the quick answer is to add `using Base::getTwo` into your `Derived` definition at class scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either:

```
class Derived : public Base {
public:
    using Base::getTwo; // Add this line
    int getValue() {
        // no matching function for call to ‘Derived::getTwo()’
        return getTwo();
    }
    int getTwo(int) {
        return 2;
    }
}
```

Or

```
        return Base::getTwo();
```

Comment: Thanks! Could you please explain why this works, too? Or rather, why it doesn't otherwise?

Comment: @RPFeltz: It is called *hiding*, and basically the process is that lookup starts in the closest context (starts inside `getValue()` method + ADL) and tries to find `getTwo()`, if it is not found, then the next scope is checked and so on. Once it finds the identifier in one context it stops the search. In your case, it finds `int getTwo(int)` inside your class, so it does not look into the base class for other overloads. The two alternative solutions are: bring the base overloads into the derived class scope with `using base::getTwo;`, so that it will be available in the class...

Comment: ... and then overload resolution will pick the most appropriate overload. The alternative solution is to qualify the call with `base::getTwo()` which will tell the compiler that you want `getTwo()` from the base class context (i.e. avoid starting lookup in the current scope and jump searching for `getTwo` inside `base`)

Answer (score 0):

This is how the name lookup in C++ works:

```
namespace N1
{
    int getTwo();
    int getTwo(int, int);

    namespace N2
    {
        int getTwo(int);

        namespace N3
        {
            call getTwo(something char*);
        }
    }
}
```

The current context is N3. There is no `getTwo` on this layer. Ok, go to the upper layer. N2 contains one definition for `getTwo`. Compiler will try to use this definition and will not seach the upper context. The `getTwo` from N2 hides all definitions for `getTwo` on all upper layers. Sometimes this causes confusion with overloaded methods.

If you add `using Base::getTwo;`, you actually add a definition proxy to the inner context. The definitions of the upper context temsellves are not visible. But the proxy is visible.