# Inheritance of virtual member functions with the same name

Tags: c++, function, inheritance, g++, virtual

```
class A
{
A() {};
virtual ~A() {};
virtual void Start() {};
virtual void Start(float a) {};
};

class B : public A
{ };

class C : public A
{
virtual void Start(float a) {};
}


...
B BObj;
BObj.Start(); // -> fine, no complain from g++
...

...
C CObj;
CObj.Start(); // -> not fine -> error: no matching function for call to ‘C::Start()’
...
```

I suspect that the problem comes from that both virtual functions have the same name, but different parameter signature. What I would like to know is that this is a g++-specific error message, how it is implemented the vtable, or it is an error based on the C++ standard.

Comment: There's something missing above; the class routines are all private by default, so the code as you have written it above would emit different errors than the one you are posting...

Comment: As @fbrereto points out the visibility of your methods is limited to the class A neither B nor C inherit them.

Comment: I think the author just threw together some code quickly.  The ... in their current locations would also elicit compiler errors

Comment: I suspect this was a design decision: lets suppose that float argument in the second function were optional [i.e. virtual void Start(float a = 3) {};]  Then the definitions would be ambiguous

Comment: All the functions in A are private, so the compiler don't find them.

Comment: Thanks for correcting my sample code. I really was very tired when I wrote.

Answer (score 7):

Overloading function hides all other `Start` functions. To use them add `using A::Start`:

```
class C : public A
{
public:
using A::Start;
virtual void Start(float a) {};
}
```

Also make `Start`   public in A too.

**Edit:**  [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1628768/why-does-an-overridden-function-in-the-derived-class-hide-other-overloads-of-the) you can find why derived class hides base class functions.

Comment: But what is the reason/rationale behide this design? Thanks, kecsap

Answer (score 0):

The overload for Start in C hides all of the overloaded Start versions from A.  If you did not try to overload Start in A [i.e. Start0(), Start1(float)] you wouldnt see this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You seek to call `Start()` on a `CObj`. But there is no such function because the only function defined is the overloaded `Start(float a)` which takes in a `float` parameter.

Exactly as the compiler says.

If a `Start()` function is deflared in the `C` class, calling this function should be fine. It can be declared as virtual and ned not be defined/implemented.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
class A
{
public:
    A() {}
    virtual ~A() {}

    virtual void Start() {}
    virtual void Start(float a) {}
};

class B : public A
{
};

class C : public A
{
public:
    using A::Start;
    virtual void Start(float a) {}
};

int main ()
{
    B BObj;
    BObj.Start();

    C CObj;
    CObj.Start ();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

when you overload a function in another class, for ever call overloaded function
if else you call it. 
for example

```
class A()
{
    void start();

};
class B:public A
{
   void start();
   void Start();{A::start}//this function call it's father function
}
void main()
{
  A a;
  B b;
  a.start();//call own function,start() in A.
  b.start();//call is own function,start() in B.
  b.Start();//call start() in A.
}
```