# Whats wrong with the following code? It's not compiling

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Base
{
public:
      void Display( void )
      {
            cout<<"Base display"<<endl;
      }

      int Display( int a )
      {
            cout<<"Base int display"<<endl;
            return 0;
      }

};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:

      void Display( void )
      {
            cout<<"Derived display"<<endl;
      }
};


void main()
{
   Derived obj;
   obj.Display();  
   obj.Display( 10 );
}
```

---

```
$test1.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:  
test1.cpp:35: error: no matching function for call to ‘Derived::Display(int)’  
test1.cpp:24: note: candidates are: void Derived::Display()
```

On commenting out `obj.Display(10)`, it works.

Comment: What compiler are you using ? It looks like `gcc` but is this the most recent code ? Why you get `$test1.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:` even though you have defined main as `void main()` ?

Comment: tried with gcc and vc++. Copied code from the vc++ editor, pasted gcc output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to place -

```
using Base::Display ; // in Derived class
```

---

If a method name is matched in the `Derived` class, compiler will not look in to the `Base` class. So, to avoid this behavior, place `using Base::Display;`. Then the compiler will look into the `Base` class if there is any method that can actually take `int` as argument for `Display`.

```
class Derived : public Base
{
    public:
    using Base::Display ;
    void Display( void )
    {
        cout<<"Derived display"<<endl;
    }
};
```

Comment: is this something compiler-specific?

Comment: It works with the using. Could you please explain me whats happening without the using?

Comment: Shouldn't int Display(int) get derived anyway as it's declared as public.

Comment: @Gunner : Its gets derived but is hidden in the derived class.

Comment: @Gunner - It gets derived. But the problem is both the base and derived class has a method bearing same name. So, it is hidden.

Comment: @Prasoon: Why is it kept hidden if it got derived. What is the notion behind that?

Comment: @Gunner : For historical reasons. Read my answer.

Comment: @Mahesh: The name maybe same, but signature is different. It should be possible to invoke it without any ambiguity of redefinition.

Comment: @Gunner - In `void Display( void );` - **Display** is the method name, right ?

Comment: @Mahesh,Prasoon Saurav: I read the historical reason and now it's clear to me. Thanks all for the clarification.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the `using` declaration. A member function named `f` in a class `X` ***hides*** all other members named `f` in the base classes of `X`.

**Why?**

Read [this explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1628768/why-does-an-overridden-function-in-the-derived-class-hide-other-overloads-of-the/1629074#1629074) by AndreyT

You can bring in those hidden names by using a `using` declaration:

`using Base::Display` is what you need to include in the derived class.

Furthermore `void main()` is non-standard. Use `int main()`

Comment: He has defined main as `void main()` but how come he gets `$test1.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:` ?

Comment: @Muggen: It's illegal to declare `main` as having a return type of anything other than `int`. This particular implementation seems to just ignore this error and treat the code as if it declared `main` correctly.

Answer (score 2):

You are masking the original function definition by creating a function in the derived class with the same name: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/strange-inheritance.html#faq-23.8