# Loss of inherited method when class used as a template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does an overridden function in the derived class hide other overloads of the base class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1628768/why-does-an-overridden-function-in-the-derived-class-hide-other-overloads-of-the)

I am having a problem with using an inherited method in a class used as a template parameter. like the below:

```
class D
{
};

class A
{
public:
        void f( D &d ){};
};

class B: public A
{
public:
        void f( int ) {};
};

template<typename F>
class C
{
public:
        void doit() { D d; f->f(d); };
        F *f;
};

int main()
{
        C<B> cb;
        cb.doit();
}
```

This is what I get trying to compile it:

```
g++ testtemplate.cpp 
testtemplate.cpp: In member function ‘void C<F>::doit() [with F = B]’:
testtemplate.cpp:28:   instantiated from here
testtemplate.cpp:21: error: no matching function for call to ‘B::f(D&)’
testtemplate.cpp:14: note: candidates are: void B::f(int)
```

However, if I remove the    void f( int ) {} method, the compiler finds the original method f( D &d ). Looks like the original method is shadowed by the new one. I want to know why.

Comment: Look at http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/strange-inheritance.html#faq-23.8

Answer (score 1):

You can do this

```
class B: public A
{
public:
    using A::f;
    void f( int ) {};
};
```

Basically [re-declaring the base class method with a different signature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1628768/why-does-an-overridden-function-in-the-derived-class-hide-other-overloads-of-the) hides all base class methods with the same name.

Answer (score 1):

Yes indeed, the method `B.f` hides `A.f`. If you want it to be available in `B`, you need an using directive :

```
class B: public A
{
public:
    using A::f;
    void f( int ) {};
};
```

Answer (score 0):

A member of a derived class will *hide* any base-class members with the same name. In order to make `A::f` available in `B`, you need a using declaration:

```
class B: public A
{
public:
    using A::f;         // <--- add this
    void f( int ) {};
};
```