# Fold expresion & CRTP

Tags: c++, templates, fold-expression

I'm writing this small application trying to test about fold expressions and i can't get it to compile, it complaints about ambiguous request on method Play, i don't understand why the signature of the function Play should be different on both calls..

```
#include <iostream>
#include <any>

using namespace std;

struct A
{
   void play() const
   {
       std::cout << "A..." << std::endl;
   }
};

struct B
{
   void play() const
   {
       std::cout << "B..." << std::endl;
   }
};

template<typename TKey>
struct BaseValue
{
    void Play(const TKey& arg)
    {
        arg.play();
    }
};

template<typename... Keys>
struct MyMap : public BaseValue<Keys>...
{
    
};

int main()
{
    MyMap<A, B> oMyMap;
    
    A a;
    oMyMap.Play(a)

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm nitpicking but I don't see a fold expression here.

Comment: One error is that you pass `arg` by const reference, but the method `play()` is non-const.

Comment: I think the problem is that the compiler has to choose between `BaseValue<A>::Play` and `BaseValue<B>::Play` before it considers the function signatures. This is name lookup, which happens before overload resolution. Name lookup does not consider function signatures.

Comment: @davidhigh Even after fixing that issue, the issue described above remains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beside the `const`ness mentioned in the comment, the fix is

```
template<typename... Keys>
struct MyMap : public BaseValue<Keys>...
{
    using BaseValue<Keys>::Play ...;
};
```

The initial problem, has to do with name-lookup, which happens before overload resolution, see [this answer] https://stackoverflow.com/a/60775944/2412846) and the linked duplicates.

Comment: Then it's a fold expression as in your answer. But the behaviour here is similar to the one in the OP.