# Accessing overloaded method from a parent class

Tags: c++, inheritance, overloading

I have stumbled upon this code, and I can't understand, why do I need to specify the class I want to call the method with one argument from? What's more interesting, if I remove the second overloaded method with two parameters, everything will work fine.

```
class A {
public:
    virtual void foo(int a) const final {};
    virtual void foo(int a, int b) const = 0;
};

class B : public A {
public:
    void foo(int a, int b) const override {}
};

int main() {
    B b;
    b.A::foo(1); // Why do I need to specify A::foo??
    // b.foo(1) -- won't compile
}
```

Comment: "if I remove the second overloaded method with two parameters" what exactly do you mean? If you remove `A::foo` then `B` breaks, because `B::foo` is declared as `override`. Instead of describing what to modify on the code, better show the modified code

Comment: Having a method in a child class with the same name as method in parent class *shadows* all the methods from parent class. You can add `using A::foo();` in `B` class to bring them back.

Comment: Probably duplicate: [overloading base class method in derived class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16835897/overloading-base-class-method-in-derived-class)

Comment: Overloading only applies to names defined in the same scope. There is only one `foo` defined in `B`, so calling it with a single argument is an error.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number What I mean is that if I remove foo(int, int) from both class A and class B, then the code will be compiled if we uncomment the last line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because what `b` sees is the overloaded instance of `foo(int a, int b)`, which preforms [name hiding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32946364/c-inheritance-and-name-hiding), therefore `foo(int a, int b)` makes `foo(int a)` invisible from `b`. If you want to make `foo(int a)`, you should specify that it should look in `class A`, that's why you need `A::`

Comment: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/strange-inheritance#hiding-rule found a link for more info

Answer (score 0):

It is because when you override `foo` in `B`, the other overloads `foo` from base `A` are masked. It is a feature of language.