# Inheritance and polymorphism in C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism

my question is about inheritance and polymorphism in C++.

```
class Base
{
public:
    virtual void f() { cout << "Base::f()" << endl; }
    void f(string s) { cout << "Base::f(string)" << endl; }
};

class Derivate1: public Base
{
public:
    void f() { cout << "Derivate1::f()" << endl; }
    void f(int i) { cout << "Derivate1::f(int)" <<endl; }

};

class Derivate2: public Base
{
public:
    void f() { cout << "Derivate2::f()" << endl; }
    void f(char c) { cout << "Derivate2::f(char)" << endl; }
};


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

//with base pointers
    Derivate1 d1;
    Derivate2 d2;
    Base *b1 = &d1;
    Base *b2 = &d2;

    b1->f();           //output: Derivate1::f() ok.
    b1->f("string");   //output: Base::f(string) ok.
    b1->f(1);        //error !

    b2->f();           //output: Derivate2::f() ok.
    b2->f("string");   //output: Base::f(string) ok.
    b2->f('c');      //error !

//with direct derivate object
    d1.f();           //output: Derivate1::f() ok.
    d1.f("string");   //error !
    d1.f(1);          //output: Derivate1::f(int) ok.

    d2.f();           //output: Derivate2::f() ok.
    d2.f("string");   //error !
    d2.f('c');        //output: Derivate2::f(char) ok.

return 0;
}
```

If i want to use a redefined function in base class which is accessible in derived object, what i have to do? I don't want to use `Base::f;` in derived classes.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does an overridden function in the derived class hide other overloads of the base class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1628768/why-does-an-overridden-function-in-the-derived-class-hide-other-overloads-of-the)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C++ is usually very strict on this type of inheritance, if you'd like a work around you could use this to solve issues like this `d1.f();`  :

```
static_cast<Base*>(&d1)->f("string");
```

if you'd like to make calls like this:   `b1->f(1);` well.. you can't. That's the whole point of polymorphism. You'd have to declare a virtual method in the `Base` class that has a method named `f(int i)` so that the compiler can link the `Base` class method and the `Derivate1` class method:

```
class Base
{
public:
  //...
    virtual void f(int i) { printf("Base::f(int)"); }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

In this case you need to tell C++ that you want to include the base class definition of `f` in the derived class.  This is done with a `using` statement

```
class Derivate1: public Base
{
public:
  using Base::f;
  ...
};

class Derivate2: public Base
{
public:
  using Base::f;
  ...
};
```

This essentially tells the C++ compiler to include both the derived class and parent class definitions of `f` when doing name lookup.  Without this the C++ compiler will essentially stop at the first type in the hierarchy which has a member named `f` and consider only the overloads declared in that type.

Comment: This will work only with direct derivate object access, not with base pointers.

Comment: @RaduGabor The issue you have with base pointers is that you can't "inject" new methods the way your are trying to do. If you want to call a method through a base pointer, then you must have declared it in the base class. `using` is the right solution for your other cases.