# Method of a class overrides all methods of another class

Tags: c++, overriding

Method `func` from `DerivedClass` override the method `func` and all its overloads from `BaseClass`.

```
#include <cstdio>

class BaseClass
{
    public:
        void func(int a){puts("BaseClass::func(int)");};
        void func(int a, int b){puts("BaseClass::func(int, int)");};
        void func(int a, int b, int c){puts("BaseClass::func(int, int, int)");};
        //...
};

class DerivedClass : public BaseClass
{
    public:        
        void func(int a){puts("DerivedClass::func(int)");}
        //...             
};

int main()
{           
    DerivedClass obj;
    obj.func(0);
    obj.func(0, 0);     // error
    obj.func(0, 0, 0);  // error      

    return 0;
}
```

How can I fix this code to end up on the screen was derived:

```
DerivedClass::func(int)
BaseClass::func(int, int)
BaseClass::func(int, int, int)
```

**Edit 1**
In functions `main` should not change anything

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The derived class's member function doesn't override the base class ones, it *hides* them. To bring them all to scope, use a `using` declaration:

```
class DerivedClass : public BaseClass
{
    public:        
        void func(int a){puts("DerivedClass::func(int)");}
        using BaseClass::func;
        //...             
};
```

[**Live example**](http://ideone.com/Zkuyn9)

Answer (score 2):

It's by design: the phenomenon is called "**name hiding**".

[**Short answer**]:

C++ doesn't like the idea that a long-standing behavior as calling one base-function with a specific set of parameters can be modified in one of your subclasses and chose to **hide all overloads in every base class** to solve this.

[**Long answer**] here: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/1629074/1938163

---

As a workaround you can cast the object to the appropriate base and call the functions you need (there's a cast penalty though), or better call the function you need directly by specifying its base class

```
int main()
{           
    DerivedClass obj;
    obj.func(0);
    obj.BaseClass::func(0,0);

    return 0;
}
```

[**Live Example**](http://ideone.com/gJ7Xc0)

or you can un-hide them with a "using directive"

```
class DerivedClass : public BaseClass
{
    public:        
        void func(int a){puts("DerivedClass::func(int)");}
        using BaseClass::func;
        //...             
};
```

[**Live Example**](http://ideone.com/Wqnb5D)

Comment: `dynamic_cast` is not needed. Can do the same with `obj.BaseClass::func(0,0);`. Besides, the question was how to design the two classes so that `func` can be called directly on `obj`.