# Compiler can't find base class method by ADL

Tags: c++, inheritance, argument-dependent-lookup

What's going on here -- why does this not compile?

```
#include <iostream>
class Base {
    void print(double d) {
        std::cout << "Base: " << d << std::endl;
    }
};

class Derived : public Base {
void print(std::string const & str) {
        std::cout << "Derived: " << str << std::endl;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    Derived d;
    d.print(2.);
    d.print("junk");
}
```

(Errors in both MinGW and VC11 with something equivalent to `No conversion from double to std::string`.)

If I change the name of the print function in `Derived`, it compiles successfully, so clearly `Derived::print(string const &)` is masking `Base::print(double)` somehow. But I was under the impression that the function signature included the argument type(s) and so this masking should occur here. Is that not correct in the case of base class methods?

Comment: This has nothing to do with ADL, which is a completely different thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not correct : name hiding occurs when a function with the same name is declared in the same scope : here `print` in `Derived` **hides** the `print` of `Base`.

Arguments names/types are ignored in this (first) step of functions lookup.

You can bring the declaration of the Base function within the Derived one with a `using` declaration:

```
using Base::print
```

If you do so, regular overload resolution will take place.

For details about *why* hiding occurs in this Derived/Base situation, I suggest [this other SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1628768/why-does-an-overridden-function-in-the-derived-class-hide-other-overloads-of-the) that perfectly answers it.

As for the standard, this particular rule is defined in section 3.3.1 :

> **Name hiding** [basic.scope.hiding]
>
> A name can be hidden by an explicit declaration of that same name in a nested declarative region
>   or derived class (10.2).

Comment: Also in the other SO post (further down) http://stackoverflow.com/a/1628786/1821972 shows how you could put class Derived : public Base { using Base::print; ... } to get what you originally expected. Excellent tutorial p.901-904 in http://www.amazon.com/Primer-3rd-Edition-Stanley-Lippman/dp/0201824701