# virtual function overriding in C++

Tags: c#, c++, oop

I have a base class with virtual function - `int Start(bool)`
In the derived there is a function with the same name but with a different signature -

```
int Start(bool, MyType *)
```

But Not virtual

In the derived `Start()`, I want to call the base class `Start()`

```
int Derived::Start(bool b, MyType *mType)
{
    m_mType = mType;
    return Start(b);
}
```

But it gives compilation error.

```
"Start' : function does not take 1 arguments"
```

However `Base::Start(b)` works

In C#, the above code works i.e the reference to Base is not required for resolving the call.

Externally if the call is made as follows

```
Derived *d = new Derived();
bool b;
d->Start(b);
```

It fails with the message:

```
Start : function does not take 1 arguments
```

But in C#, the same scenaio works.

As I understand the virtual mechanism cannot be used for resolving the call, because the two functions have different signature.

But the calls are not getting resolved as expected.

Please help

Comment: they have to match exactly - otherwise its *overloading*

Comment: Probably duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1628768/why-does-an-overridden-function-in-the-derived-class-hide-other-overloads-of-the

Comment: `In C#, the above code works `  C# is not C++.

Answer (score 4):

Your two options are either add `using Base::Start` to resolve the scope of `Start`

```
int Derived::Start(bool b, MyType *mType)
{
    using Base::Start;
    m_mType = mType;
    return Start(b);
}
```

Or as you noted add the `Base::` prefix.

```
int Derived::Start(bool b, MyType *mType)
{
    m_mType = mType;
    return Base::Start(b);
}
```

Comment: Note that Base is inside nested namespaces. So i gave - A::B::C::Base::Start . With the using option, the following error is shown in the IDE - "a class-qualified name is not allowed".

Answer (score 3):

This is due to *name hiding*.

When you declare a function in a derived class with the same name as one in the base class, the base class versions are hidden and inaccessible with an unqualified call.

You have two options: either fully qualify your call like `Base::Start(b)`, or put a `using` declaration in your class:

```
using Base::Start;
```

Comment: Using a fully qualified name looks ok when the call is from the dervied class member function. But For a call to Base::Start() from a derived class object, the second method with the using directive looks better. But this gives the error - " a fully qualified name is not allowed"