# Overloading new operator in the derived class

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, new-operator

I have overloaded `new` operator in the Base class. However, when I add additional overloaded `new` to the Derived class gcc compiler does not find `new` operator in the Base class. Why?

Best,
  Alex

```
#include <stdlib.h>
template <class t> class Base {
  public:
    Base() {}
    void * operator new (size_t size, void *loc) { return loc; }
};

template <class t> class Derived : public Base<t> {
  public:
    Derived() {}
    void * operator new (size_t size, int sz, void *loc) { return loc; }

};

void foo() {
  void *loc = malloc(sizeof(Derived<char>));
  Derived<char> *d = new (loc) Derived<char>();
}
```

gcc output:

```
   new.cpp: In function ‘void foo()’:
new.cpp:17:45: error: no matching function for call to ‘Derived<char>::operator new(sizetype, void*&)’
  Derived<char> *d = new (loc) Derived<char>();
                                             ^
new.cpp:17:45: note: candidate is:
new.cpp:11:10: note: static void* Derived<t>::operator new(size_t, int, void*) [with t = char; size_t = unsigned int]
   void * operator new (size_t size, int sz, void *loc) { return loc; }
          ^
new.cpp:11:10: note:   candidate expects 3 arguments, 2 provided
```

Comment: You have added (by mistake ?) an extra parameter to the overload in the derived class, so the `new` operator is waiting for an extra parameter.

Comment: No, I want B::new(size_t, void*) to be called in this example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you invoke the `operator new` via the placement `new` expression

```
new (loc) Derived<char>();
```

the compiler looks for an overload of `operator new` in the `Derived` class (and not the `Base` class). It finds it, but your overload

```
void * operator new (size_t size, int sz, void *loc) { return loc; }
//                                ^ additional parameter
```

accepts more parameters, hence the error.

If you ask why the compiler is not smart enough to invoke the `Base`'s overload of `operator new`, it is because of [*name hiding*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1628768/3093378): the `operator new` overload in the `Derived` class hides the one of the `Base` class. If you want to make the `Base::operator new` overload visible in your `Derived` class, use

```
using Base<t>::operator new;
```

Comment: Why the compiler does not search for public methods (including operator new) in the Base class in this case?

Comment: @Alexander Because of name hiding. The `operator new` overload in the `Derived` class hides the one of the base class. Added this in the answer.

Comment: is not the same as with standard methods? Can multiple operators new (with different parameter sets) coexist in the class tree, can't they?

Comment: @Alexander Yes they can. But the `Base` one is hidden. So if you need to use the base overload, i.e. make it visible in the `Derived` class, use `using Base<t>::operator new`.