# Pointer derived from pure virtual class(A) can't access overload method from the pure class (B)

Tags: c++, c++11, pure-virtual, name-hiding

Consider I have two pure virtual classes, one deriving from the another and a concrete class deriving from the last mentioned:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Abstract1
{
public:
    virtual ~Abstract1() { };
    virtual void method(int a) = 0;

protected:
    Abstract1() = default;
};

class Abstract2: public Abstract1
{
public:
    virtual ~Abstract2() { };
    virtual void method(char c, std::string s) = 0;

protected:
    Abstract2() = default;
};

class Concrete : public Abstract2
{
public:
    void method(int a) override
    {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "a: " << a << std::endl;
    }

    void method(char c, std::string s) override
    {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "c: " << c << "; s: " << s << std::endl;
    }
};
```

When I create a pointer of the type `Abstract2*` I can't have access to the override method from `Abstract1`.

```
int main()
{
    Concrete c;
    c.method(42);
    c.method('a', std::string("string"));

    Abstract2 *ptr_a2 = &c;
    ptr_a2->method(13); //Error
    ptr_a2->method('b', std::string("string2"));
}
```

I got the following error, saying that the only existing method is the `Absctract2` overloaded:

```
<source>: In function 'int main()':
<source>:49:22: error: no matching function for call to 'Abstract2::method(int)'

   49 |     ptr_a2->method(13);

      |                      ^

<source>:22:18: note: candidate: 'virtual void Abstract2::method(char, std::string)'

   22 |     virtual void method(char c, std::string s) = 0;

      |                  ^~~~~~

<source>:22:18: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 1 provided
```

Does anybody know why does it happen or how to fix it?
I mean, the only reasonable solution I got was to add

```
virtual void method(int a) override = 0;
```

inside `Abstract2` class.

Is it a case of "name hiding"? Why only on pointer and not on the Concrete class then? The number of parameters are different is not only a close-type thing.

Here's a link to play with it online where the example was created:
https://godbolt.org/z/gxKpzN

Comment: Interesting that it'll work (https://ideone.com/CojHlB) if you change the name in `Abstract1`. This is definitely something to do with the overloading. Also kudos for a solid short, reproducible example and well-written question. I hope we see more from you!

Comment: Yes this is [name hiding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37861389/why-c-does-not-support-overloading-across-scopes/37861586#37861586). `Abstract2::method` hides `Abstract1::method`. However, both `method` are visible in `Concrete`, which is why you can call both of them from `Concrete`. If you want `Abstract1::method` to be visible from `Abstract2` you can do a `using Abstract1::method;` inside the definition of `Abstract2`.

Comment: This makes me wonder... By issuing a `using Abstract1::method` you can "import" all overloads of method into `Abstract2`, but is there a way to import a specific one?

Comment: @Ray imho this question deserves an answer, not just a comment ;)

Comment: @j4x, that's worth a question of its own, if it hasn't already been asked.

Comment: `static_cast<Abstract1*>(ptr_a2)->method(13);`

Comment: OK @TobySpeight. I posted it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59758453/how-to-make-all-hidden-names-from-a-base-class-accessible-in-derived-one

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the name is hidden in `Abstract2` (but visible again in `Concrete`, where the override is declared).  The easiest way to make it accessible in `Abstract2` is to add a `using` statement:

```
class Abstract2: public Abstract1
{
public:
    using Abstract1::method;
    virtual void method(char c, std::string s) = 0;
};
```

Note that it's not relevant whether the member function is pure virtual or has a definition, and we see the same whether looking at a concrete `Abstract2` or a reference or pointer to type `Abstract2`.

Comment: Sure but why only on pointers? Why doesn't it happen on any case? Using the Concrete object I can access both methods.

Comment: Yes, both methods are visible when you have a `Concrete`, but when you have a `Abstract2`, then `Abstract1::method` is hidden by `Abstract2::method`.  The only reason that we're using pointers or references is that `Abstract2` is an abstract class, so we can't have an instance of it.  If you change the pure abstract member functions (replace `= 0;` with `{}`), then you can instantiate an `Abstract2` and demonstrate the issue there, too.

Comment: `void test(Abstract2& a2) { a2.method(1); }` demonstrates that it's hidden even without using pointers. The point is that you have an `Abstract2`, and with `Abstract2` the only visible `method` is the two-parameter one.