# How are overloaded virtual functions chosen when there's no `using Base_class::function_name`

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism, overloading

Here are two classes that overload a virtual function:

```
class Base
{
public:
    virtual void func(int) {
        cout<<"base int"<<endl;
    }
    virtual void func(double) {
        cout<<"base double"<<endl;
    }
};

class Deri: public Base
{
public:
    virtual void func(int) {
        cout<<"deri int"<<endl;
    }
};
```

I use these classes here:

```
int main() {
    Base * ptr = new Deri;
    ptr->func(3.0);                     //"base double"
    static_cast<Deri *>(ptr)->func(3.0);//"deri int"
    return 0;
}
```

I expected that both calls are for the base double overload, but I get the following output:

```
base double 
deri int
```

When I add the following "using" statement in `Deri`:

```
using Base::func;
```

I get all overloaded functions from the Base class and it works as expected.

What happens when I don't use this "using statement" ? I assume `ptr->func(3.0)` and `static_cast<Deri*>->func(3.0)` look for the same vtable. But how they look for different functions? What the vtable of Class Deri look like?

Comment: "*I know we usually use "using" to get all overloaded functions from the Base class.*" ... do we?

Comment: Assuming `ptr1` really means `ptr`.

Comment: You may find this interesting: [Why does an overridden function in the derived class hide other overloads of the base class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1628768/why-does-an-overridden-function-in-the-derived-class-hide-other-overloads-of-the)

Comment: My Friend, your code does not compile, @ubc_ben, since ptr1 seems to not be defined

Comment: @ArnavBorborah Sorry man, just change it to 'ptr'

Comment: @WhozCraig Exactly.

Comment: @NicolBolas Yes, in fact there is an interview question

Answer (score 0):

Look at here:http://thesyntacticsugar.blogspot.ca/2011/10/behind-scenes-name-hiding-in-c.html

It said that "When identifying possible candidates, name lookup propagates outward starting from the immediate scope. Only if no function exists with the correct name does the process continue to the next enclosing scope. Once a scope is found that has at least one viable candidate, the compiler proceeds with matching the arguments to the parameters of the various candidates, applying access rules etc".

So my understanding is the type of the pointer detemines which scope the name lookup starts. When it is the pointer of the Base class, it looks up in Class Base first. When static_cast to the Deri class, it looks up in Class Deri first.

It is notable that all three versions of func() are in the vtable of Class Deri.