# Why does gcc hide overloaded functions in the global namespace?

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-errors, namespaces, language-lawyer

```
void f() {}

namespace test
{
void f(int) {}    
void g() { f(); } // error in gcc 6.2.0
}

int main()
{
    test::g();
}
```

Compile it with **g++ -std=c++1z main.cpp**, the output is as follows:

> ```
> main.cpp: In function 'void test::g()':
> main.cpp:9:4: error: too few arguments to function 'void test::f(int)'
>   f(); // error in gcc
>     ^
> main.cpp:5:6: note: declared here
>  void f(int) {}
> ```

My compiler is gcc 6.2.0.

Why does gcc hide overloaded functions in the global namespace? Is this conforming to the C++ standard?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Why does gcc hide overloaded functions in the global namespace? Is this conforming to the C++ standards?

Yes. In short, you can't overload functions through different scopes. According to the rule of [unqualified name lookup](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/unqualified_lookup), for the invoking of `f()` in `g()`, the name `f` could be found inside the namespace `test`, then the name lookup stops; [overload resolution](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution) takes place after that (based on the names found). That means `f()` in global namespace won't be considered at all even it looks more appropriate here.

(emphasis mine)

> For an unqualified name, that is a name that does not appear to the
>   right of a scope resolution operator ::, name lookup examines the
>   scopes as described below, **until it finds at least one declaration
>   of any kind, at which time the lookup stops and no further scopes are
>   examined.**
>
> In order to compile a function call, the compiler must first perform
>   name lookup, which, for functions, may involve argument-dependent
>   lookup, and for function templates may be followed by template
>   argument deduction. **If these steps produce more than one candidate
>   function, then overload resolution is performed to select the function
>   that will actually be called.**

You can use `using` to introduce the names into the same scope, i.e. to make them actual overloaded functions.

```
namespace test
{
    using ::f;        // introduce the name from global namespace
    void f(int) {}    
    void g() { f(); } // fine
}
```

Comment: tl;dr: this is a known C++ quirk, and is the same reason that ["overloads" in a derived class hide variants in a base class](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1628768/560648), requiring `using Base::foo` under some circumstances.