# Why a method of parent of parent classes' not accessible without of explicit scope resolution?

Tags: c++, oop, overriding, overloading, name-hiding

Let's consider this code:

```
struct message
{
  uint8_t* data;
  size_t length;
};

class device_base
{
  // ...
public:
  virtual ssize_t exec(uint8_t cmd, const uint8_t* data = nullptr, size_t length = 0);
  inline ssize_t exec(uint8_t cmd, const message& msg)
  {
    return exec(cmd, msg.data, msg.length);
  }
  // ...
};

class device : public device_base
{
  // The exec method do not overloaded or overridden here.
};

class device_uart : public device
{
  // ...
public:
  ssize_t exec(uint8_t cmd, const uint8_t* data = nullptr, size_t length = 0);
  void some_method(const message&);
  // ...
};

// ...

void device_uart::some_method(const message& msg)
{
  // exec(SOME_COMMAND, msg); // The inline method device_base::exec is invisible here by some reason.
  device::exec(SOME_COMMAND, msg); // OK.
  device_base::exec(SOME_COMMAND, msg); // OK too.
  exec(SOME_COMMAND, msg.data, msg.length); // OK, of course.
}
```

Why the inline non-virtual method `exec` is not seen in the `device_uart` class?

Comment: It's been awhile since I poured over it, but I'm pretty sure [**this question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1628768/why-does-an-overridden-function-in-the-derived-class-hide-other-overloads-of-the) covers exactly what you seem to be asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why the inline non-virtual method `exec` is not seen in the `device_uart` class?

This is a kind of "name-hiding"; in the member function of class `device_uart`, `device_base::exec` is hidden because there's a method with same name `exec` in the class `device_uart` itself. Functions can't be overloaded through different scopes.

According to the rule of [unqualified name lookup](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/unqualified_lookup):

> name lookup examines the scopes as described below, until it finds at
>   least one declaration of any kind, at which time the lookup stops and
>   no further scopes are examined.

That means the name `exec` will be found at the scope of `device_uart`, then name lookup stops, the names in the base class won't be considered for overload resolution at all.

To solve the issue, you can use scope resolution operator :: to make it [qualified name lookup](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/qualified_lookup) as you've shown; or
you can use `using` to introduce the names into the same scope, the overload resolution would take effect as expected. e.g.

```
class device_uart : public device
{
  // ...
  using device_base::exec; // introduce the names from base class into the same scope
public:
  // ...
};
```