# Why does an override method in subclass hide superclass's in C++, but not in Java?

Tags: java, c++, inheritance, overriding

I notice that in `Java`, if you override a method in subclass, you can still call the overriden method declaced only in superclass. But in `C++`, it will be hiden.

The Java code:

```
class Fish {
    public void foo() {}
}

class Tuna extends Fish {
    public void foo(int i) {}
}

public class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Tuna t = new Tuna();
        t.foo();
        t.foo(1);
    }
}
```

The C++ code:

```
class Fish {
public:
    void foo() {}
};

class Tuna : public Fish {
public:
    void foo(int i) {}
};
int main() {
    Tuna t;
    t.foo(1); // ok
    t.foo(); // error
    return 0;
}
```

I noticed some people present a few explanations in the [Why does an overridden function in the derived class hide other overloads of the base class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1628768/why-does-an-overridden-function-in-the-derived-class-hide-other-overloads-of-the) . If it is true that

> name hiding would prove to be a lesser evil

, why do`Java` choose a **more evil** way?

Why do `Java` and `C++` behave different? Is it only becasue of the different name looking-up strategies between `Java` and `C++`?

Comment: I don't know if anyone here can tell you why.  Probably only James Gosling could.  But I spotted the overloading right away.  If you're an experienced Java programmer this just isn't a problem.

Comment: I suggest tremoving subjective and inflammatory terms like "evil" from a question to make it more objective. It sounds a bit like a ["rant in disguise"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) currently.

Comment: Why can a tuna breathe water but an ocelot can't? Java and C++ aren't the same. Why should any particular feature match between them?

Comment: Different isn't the same.