# Why are function overloads of base classes inaccessible

Tags: c++, inheritance, overloading, c++17

Consider the following example:

```
struct Base
{
    void foo()
    {
        cout << "Base foo\n";
    }

    void bar()
    {
        cout << "Base bar\n";
    }
};

struct Derivate : public Base
{
    void foo(int x)
    {
        cout << "Derivate foo\n";
    }
};
```

If we create two instances, like

```
Base a;
Derivate b;
```

The `Base` object `a` can call its member functions as usual (`a.foo(); a.bar();`).

When using `b` the call `b.bar()` works as expected but since I overloaded `Base::foo()` it's not possible to call `b.foo()`.

Why is that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1628768/why-does-an-overridden-function-in-the-derived-class-hide-other-overloads-of-the

Answer (score -1):

You didn't overload `Base::foo`, instead you've hid it. And it is still accessible, it can be called like this:

```
static_cast<Base &>(b).foo();
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I'd guess whoever did, did so because you mix up "overload" and *override*. What is shown *does* overload. What requires a virtual function in the base is overridding.

Comment: `Base::foo` is indeed *overloaded* (and also *hidden*) by `Derivate::foo`. The fact that it's virtual prevents it from being *overridden*, not *overloaded*. And while the provided workaround does indeed work, a `using` declaration would be a much cleaner solution.

Comment: @Angew It is not overloaded because it does not participate in overload resolution at all (unless `using Base::foo;` is used).

Comment: You're right that I misspoke about the overload bit.