# Overload pure virtual function with non pure virtual version

Tags: c++

With Base and Derived defined like this:

```
class Base {

    public:
        virtual int f1(int a) const = 0;
        virtual int f2(int a, int b) const { return a+b;}
};

class Derived : public Base {

    public:
        int f1(int a) const { return a; }
}; 

int main() {
    Derived obj;
    cout << obj.f1(1) << endl;
    cout << obj.f2(1, 2) << endl;
}
```

The result is

```
1
3
```

*obj.f1(1)* uses the *f1* implementation from *Derived* and *obj.f2(1, 2)* uses the implementation inherited from *Base*, which is what I want.

Now, I would like these two functions to have the same name, *f*, so the base class provides an implementation when there are two parameters and the derived class must implement the single parameter version (that's why it's pure virtual).

However, if I do this (just rename *f1* and *f2* to *f*):

```
class Base {

    public:
        virtual int f(int a) const = 0;
        virtual int f(int a, int b) const { return a + b;}
};

class Derived : public Base {

    public:
        int f(int a) const { return a; }
};

int main() {
    Derived obj;
    cout << obj.f(1) << endl;
    cout << obj.f(1, 2) << endl;
}
```

I get the following error:

```
20:23: error: no matching function for call to 'Derived::f(int, int)'
20:23: note: candidate is:
14:13: note: virtual int Derived::f(int) const
14:13: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided
```

Why is this? Is it not possible to do this kind of overloading?

Comment: @StoryTeller It is, indeed. When I did the research I thought it had something to do with one of the functions being pure virtual, so I guess that's why I didn't find that question. This answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1629074/1755482 gives a nice explanation of the *name hiding* phenomenon.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to write

```
class Derived : public Base {

    public:
        using Base::f;
        int f(int a) const { return a; }
};
```

Note the `using` statement. That brings the base class version back into scope.

Answer (score 8):

> Now, I would like these two functions to have the same name, `f`

You need to write

```
class Derived : public Base {

    public:
        using Base::f;
        int f(int a) const { return a; }
};
```

Note the `using` statement. That brings the base class version back into scope. [Thanks to @Bathsheba]

> Why is this? Is it not possible to do this kind of overloading?

No, not possible as written in the original question due to [[basic.scope.hiding¶3]](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic#scope.hiding-3):

> In a member function definition, the declaration of a name at block
>   scope hides the declaration of a member of the class with the same
>   name; see [basic.scope.class]. **The declaration of a member in a
>   derived class hides the declaration of a member of a base class of the
>   same name;** see [class.member.lookup].

This clause is about *names*, not overloads. As such, it doesn't matter if there are other overloads in the base class, **they all share the same *name***, which is hidden according to quote above.

Comment: Do please feel free to copy my answer into the top of this one; it would read much better with it.

Comment: Reads very nicely now - have an upvote!

Comment: @Bathsheba Shall we also downvote your answer to be even more supportive? :)

Comment: Ha. @lubgr: Feel free - it's not as good as this answer.

Comment: @Bathsheba "This answer is not useful" certainly doesn't apply to your fixed-OP's-issue-in-10-seconds post.

Comment: @lubgr: You're so nice ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can either pull all definitions of Base into scope with by writing `using Base::f;` or you can explcitily write for some versions of f something like this: `int f(int a, int b) const override {return Base::f(a,b);}`

```
class Derived : public Base {

public:
    int f(int a) const { return a; }
    int f(int a, int b) const override {return Base::f(a,b);} 
};
```

The version with using is already mentioned in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52364776/4290866):

```
class Derived : public Base {

    public:
        using Base::f;
        int f(int a) const { return a; }
};
```

**Note:** I know that the second version does not work on MSVC 2010. I am also aware this compiler is ancient, but just for people who care ;)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other solutions, if you don't want to redefine `f` you could explicitly invoke `f` of the base class using

```
int main() {
    Derived obj;
    cout << obj.f1(1) << endl;
    cout << obj.Base::f2(1, 2) << endl;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can also make them all pure and then override them in the derived class. And you can continue to use your class as you want.

Comment: The problem with this answer is that you're inflicting extra work on the descendent to actually implement f2().  The original f2() is not pure virtual presumably because the base implementation is sufficient for many (most?) of their use-cases, but wanted to leave it open for descendants to override it should it become necessary.

Comment: @AndreKostur, your are completely right on this point.