# C++ Parent and child classes have method with same name

Tags: c++, oop

Let's have following classes parent and child.

```
class parent
{

public:
    void Test(char* pParameter) {};
};

class child : parent
{
public:
    void Test(int pParameter) {};
};
```

How to solve following issue?

```
child* c = new child();
c->Test("cccc");
```

It returns: "const char *" is incompatible with parameter of type "int".

I found out these ways:

1. Rename method
2. Cast c to parent class ((parent*)c->Test("cccc");)
3. Create in child class method Test(char*) calling the method in parent class.

I do not like neither one of the solutions. Is there any other?

Comment: Add `using parent::Test;` into `child` class.

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1628768/why-does-an-overridden-function-in-the-derived-class-hide-other-overloads-of-the) doesn't really answer your question, but hopefully explains the reason for the problem.

Comment: And why should it be available because on top of name hiding, you are also using private inheritance.