# On inheriting public overridden methods

Tags: c++

I have the following code:

```
class A
{
public:
   virtual void foo( void ) = 0;
   virtual void foo( int )  { }
};

class B : public A
{
public:
   virtual void foo( void ) override  { }
};

class C : public B
{
public:
   virtual void foo( int n ) override
   {
      B::foo( n );
   }
};
```

I checked that code with different compilers and all of them show the same bug:
There is no B::foo(n) function to call inside the C::foo(int) function.

According to my non-so-updated c++ knowledge:

1. A has two different functions signatures.
2. `B` overrides `foo()`: a pure virtual function of class `A`. It inherits `foo(int)` for free. In other words, `foo(int)` should be a function available to the public interface of `B`.
3. The public interface of `C` should have the `foo()` function inherited from `B` and overrides `foo(int)` function that should be available from the public interface of `B`. Inside `C::foo(int)` I would call its overridden method from `B`, `B::foo(int)`.

*What were you expecting?*
Since `B` inherits publicly from A, it should have in its public interface foo(int) and from that
I would expect to call B::foo(int) inside C::foo(int).

Comment: As instructed in [ask], can you please write a descriptive, non-ambiguous title? For more guidance, see [How do I write a good title?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/10647/997587)

Comment: I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1628768/why-does-an-overridden-function-in-the-derived-class-hide-other-overloads-of-the?rq=2) is related. Note that both calling `A::foo(n);` and putting `using A::foo;` in the definition of `B` work. Not sure what the exact mechanism is here though.