# Overloading a method in a subclass in C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, overloading

Suppose I have some code like this:

```
class Base {
    public:
      virtual int Foo(int) = 0;
};

class Derived : public Base {
    public:
      int Foo(int);
      virtual double Foo(double) = 0;
};

class Concrete : public Derived {
    public:          
      double Foo(double);
};
```

If I have a object of type Concrete, why can I not call Foo(int)?
If I change the name of Foo(double) so that it isn't overloading Foo, then all is well and both methods are accessible, but this isn't what I want.
Similarly, if I remove Concrete class and implement Foo(double) in Derived, then both are accessible, but again, not what I want.

Comment: I don't understand the problem.  GCC versions 3.3.6 and 4.2.4 both compile this code without complaint.

Comment: Because of implicit conversion of integers to doubles - try adding tracing to the functions and do `Concrete c; int i=1; c.Foo(i);`

Comment: Isn't that called overriding if you redefine a virtual method in a subclass?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Name lookup happens before overload resolution, so once `Foo` has been found in `Concrete`, base classes won't be search for other methods called `Foo`. `int Foo(int)` in `Derived` is hidden by the `Foo` in `Concrete`.

You have a number of options.

Change the call to be explicit.

```
concrete.Derived::Foo(an_int);
```

Add a using declaration to Concrete.

```
class Concrete : public Derived {
public:          
   using Derived::Foo;
   double Foo(double);
};
```

Call the function through a base reference.

```
Derived& dref = concrete;
dref.Foo(an_int);
```

Answer (score 6):

`Foo(double)` hides the function from your base. You can make it visible though:

```
class Concrete : public Derived 
{
public:          
  using Derived::Foo;
  double Foo(double);
};
```

Comment: A good explanation can be found at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/411103/function-with-same-name-but-different-signature-in-derived-class/411112#411112