# final virtual functions in C++0x

Tags: c++11, virtual, final

Reading that you can have [final virtual functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B0x#Finalized_classes_and_virtual_functions) in C++0x I am bit confused. What is the difference to just omitting both modifiers in the first place?

Comment: consider, in the example, if `Base` inherited from another class which declares the initial base `f` method.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The difference occurs it's not the base that uses it, but the derived.

```
class Base {
    virtual void foo() = 0;
};
class Derived : Base {
    void foo() {} 
    // Still virtual because it's virtual in base- no way to "un-virtual" it

    virtual void foo() final {} 
    // Now un-overridable.
};
```

Think of it not as preventing overrides, but preventing "any more" overrides.

Comment: Thanks! It was not clear to me, that the virtual gets carried through the entire hierarchy.

Answer (score 1):

When I first came across the use of the `final` keyword in conjunction with `virtual` in C++, I was wondering the same thing:

> If declaring a method [`virtual`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_function) makes it inheritable and overridable, and declaring a method [`final`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8824587/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-final-keyword-in-c11-for-functions) prevents that method from being overriden, doesn't declaring a method *both* form a contradiction?

I think the current [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6788376/4009370) to this question is good, but I wanted to build upon it a bit more based on what I found looking into this.

Consider the following class:

```
class A {
    public:
        void hide_me();
        virtual void override_me();
        virtual void cant_override_me() final;
};
```

The important thing to realize is that the three method declarations are all distinct and mean different things.

The first:

```
    void hide_me();
```

is non-virtual and thus, by definition, cannot be overridden.

The third:

```
    virtual void cant_override_me() final;
```

is declared `final`, and thus cannot be overridden, also by definition.

The difference is that since `hide_me` is non-virtual, overriding it is *unapplicable*, whereas you can think of `cant_override_me` as *eligible* to be overridden (because it is `virtual`,) **but** it also has overriding *disabled* due to the `final` modifier. In other words, overriding doesn't apply to methods that are not declared `virtual`, but it does apply to `virtual` methods, you just can't override them if they are also declared `final`.

Now consider a child class:

```
class B: public A {
    public:
        void hide_me(); // this hide's A's definition of "hide_me()"; this is not overriding.
        void override_me(); // implicit "virtual"
        //void cant_override_me(); // implicit "virtual"; compilation fails
};
```

You **can** redefine `hide_me()` for class `B`, but this is just overloading or [hiding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/411103/function-with-same-name-but-different-signature-in-derived-class), hence the function name. `B` can still access `A`'s `hide_me` method via `A::hide_me()`, but someone else who has a reference to `B` declared as `B`, i.e.:

```
B *my_b = new B();
```

must access `A`'s now-hidden definition of `hide_me` via `my_b->A::hide_me()`.

You **cannot** provide a redefinition of `cant_override_me()` in `B`.

As a full example, here is a slight redefinition of the program to help exemplify what's going on:

```
#include <cstdio>    
class A {
    public:
        inline void hide_me() {
            printf("a hide_me\n");
        }
        virtual void override_me();
        virtual void cant_override_me() final;
};

class B: public A {
    public:
        inline void hide_me() {
            printf("b hide_me\n");
        }
        void override_me();
        inline void foo() {
            A::hide_me();
        }
        // can't override cant_override_me
};

void A::override_me() {
    printf("a override_me\n");
}

void A::cant_override_me() {
    printf("a cant_override_me\n");
}

void B::override_me() {
    printf("b override_me\n");
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    A *a = new A();
    A *ab = new B();
    B *b = new B();

    a->hide_me();
    ab->hide_me();
    b->hide_me();
    b->A::hide_me();

    printf("---\n");

    a->override_me();
    ab->override_me();
    b->override_me();
    b->A::override_me();
}
```

The program outputs

```
a hide_me
a hide_me
b hide_me
a hide_me
---
a override_me
b override_me
b override_me
a override_me
```