# Is there any sense in marking a base class function as both virtual and final?

Tags: c++, c++11, virtual, final

In [various](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11#Explicit_overrides_and_final) [explanations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8824587/purpose-of-the-final-keyword/8824618#8824618) of C++11's `final` keyword, I'm seeing examples like this.

```
class base
{
public:
    virtual void f() final;
};

class derived : public base
{
public:
    virtual void f();    // Illegal due to base::f() declared final.
};
```

Is this actually a useful use of `final`? Why would you declare a virtual function in a base class (implying that it will be usefully overrideable in derived classes) and then immediately mark it as `final` (negating that implication)? What is the utility of `virtual void f() final`?

I can see the value of marking `derived::f()` final rather than `base::f()`. In this case, `base::f()` presumably had a good design-based reason for why `f()` should be virtual, and `derived::f()` separately has a good design-based reason for why no further-derived class should override its implementation.

If you don't want the function overridden polymorphically, why not just leave off the virtual keyword? Of course, derived classes might still override the function non-polymorphically. Is the purpose of `virtual void f() final` in the base class therefore to make `base::f()` firmly non-overrideable in any way—either as a virtual or non-virtual function? If so, then it seems a bit unfortunate that we must add the `virtual` keyword in this case only to enable use of `final`. I would think that it should then be legal to mark even non-virtual functions as final.

Why use `virtual void f() final` for a function originating in a base class when the sense of `virtual` and the sense of `final` seem to contradict?

Comment: Examples are *examples*; they're intended to show what the feature does, not necessarily how exactly to use it. This way uses only two classes to show what `final` means. To use a real-world example would require *three*: one to initiate the virtual, one to derive from it and be `final`, and a third to attempt to derive from it and overload it. This way is shorter.

Comment: @NicolBolas I understand the purpose of examples. But does this particular type of example also demonstrate a useful paradigm for use? That's the question.

Answer (score 25):

> Is there any sense in marking a base class function as both virtual and final?

Yes, at least temporarily.

I found myself in a relatively large and unfamiliar existing C++ source code base.  Much of the code was written prior to C++11.  I found that I wanted to ensure that all overrides of a virtual function in a base class were marked with `override`.  The hard part is locating all of those overrides.

I marked the virtual function in the base class with `final`, and the compiler quickly showed me where every single override was declared.  It was then very easy to decorate the overrides how I wanted, and remove the `final` from the virtual in the base class.

Answer (score 4):

You can mark it `virtual` to indicate that it is 'virtual' in the class you are inheriting from (even though you don't have to do this), and mark it `final` to indicate that no class deriving from your class may override it further. This may happen when you are implementing an abstract base class, for example. This is C++11, so it's not useful; `override` is a much better indication, since it is enforced by the compiler.

Another possibility: you want this method not to be overridden, but you want to be able to change that without recompilation. Remember that `virtual` means it is in the virtual table. even if the compiler will not let you override it.

I think the purpose of the example you have shown is to demonstrate priorities between `virtual` and final, and nothing more. It is a *minimal* use of `final`, not a useful one.

Marking a non-virtual method as `final` makes no sense, since you cannot override them anyway. If you want the compiler to prevent hiding, that is a completely different issue, that has nothing to do with the method being `final`. In a sense, non-virtual methods are final already, but hidable.

Comment: Marking a function as `virtual` does not indicate that it is `virtual` in a base. It indicates that it is `virtual` in the class being defined, regardless of what a base class may or may not have done.

Comment: @Pete Becker: I think he meant in terms of making the code self-documenting.  It's common practice to respecify the virtual keyword when overriding a base (especially before C++11 added the override specifier) just so the programmer reading the detived clasd definition knows that a particular method is virtual.

Comment: @SeanMiddleditch - that's clearly **not** what he said.

Comment: That's not "clear" at all, but hey, English. It's weird.

Comment: @PeteBecker, maybe that's not what you understood, but that's exactly what I meant. I thought 'indicate' is clear enough; turns out it isn't, so if you have a better way to phrase it, you are welcome to edit the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

The alternative is a non-virtual function. But non-virtual function can be hidden by a derived class. So if you want to prevent a function hiding, it can be specified as virtual final one.