# Does it make sense to add final keyword to the virtual function in a class that has no base class (is not derived)

Tags: c++, c++11, final, virtual-functions

I am reading an awesome [awesome C++11 tutorial](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/cpp11-language-classes#final) and the author provides this example while explaining the `final` keyword:

```
struct B {
    virtual void f() const final;   // do not override
    virtual void g();
};
struct D : B {
    void f() const;     // error: D::f attempts to override final B::f
    void g();       // OK
};
```

So does it make sense using here the `final` keyword? In my opinion you can just avoid using the `virtual` keyword here and prevent `f()` from being overridden.

Comment: I don't want to knock it, since a guru may come along and present a use-case where it solves some really obscure compilation error... But it looks like a silly thing to do.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any sense in marking a base class function as both virtual and final?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16739135/is-there-any-sense-in-marking-a-base-class-function-as-both-virtual-and-final)

Comment: Actually there are more duplicates, e.g. [What's the point of a final virtual function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11704406/)

Comment: Why are there 3 close requests? How is the question **not** legitimate?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

If you don't mark the function as `virtual` and `final` then the child-class can still implement the function and hide the base-class function.

By making the function `virtual` and `final` the child-class can not override *or* hide the function.

Comment: I knew a guru would come along. Although I think this is a bit too much in the way of overhead (that may or may not be elided), just to prevent hiding. +1.

Comment: Apparently there is consensus on the matter, but I for one would like an explanation on how doing nothing useful *and* breaking another language feature would be considered a benefit.

Comment: @Quentin its removing the possibility of ambiguity, e.g. in the case of `template <DerivedFromB> void doStuff(DerivedFromB & b) { b.f(); }`, you can be 100% sure where that `f()` call goes

Comment: @Caleth why would you make it a template and perform an unqualified member call if you want a specific `f` to be called?

Comment: @Quentin that's a minimal contrived example, but it applies where you have other reasons for the template

Comment: @Caleth `b.B::f();` will work as you expect even if the static type of `b` is `D`.

Comment: I think we disagree with what "useful" includes. I consider turning run-time logic errors into compile-time errors "useful". The point is that the writer of B can constrain the writer of D.

Comment: @Caleth I have no idea what "runtime logic error" you're talking about. You want to call `B::f`, just call it. I appreciate your effort at coming up with an example, but here there is simply no point in writing a completely general `b.f()` (i.e. call the statically most-derived `f`), only to cripple the ability to actually hide `f` afterwards. The result is the same, but now the developper of `D` and `D`'s descendants gets that `virtual` kludge and cannot use `f` anymore.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145009/discussion-between-caleth-and-quentin).

Comment: @Caleth: `class D : public B { virtual void f(int=0); }`. Who says I can't "override" `B::f` ? Quentin's solution `b.B::f()`  _does_ work as intended here.

Answer (score 11):

Yes! In the example you provide, the `final` keyword prevents any derived classes from overriding `f()` as you correctly say. If the function is non-virtual, `D:f()` is allowed to *hide* the base class version of the function:

```
struct B {
    void f() const;   // do not override
    virtual void g();
};
struct D : B {
    void f() const; // OK!
    void g();       // OK
};
```

By making `f()` a `virtual` and `final` function, any attempt at overriding or hiding causes a compile error.

Answer (score 3):

Your intuition is right: making a function `virtual` only to immediately cap it with `final` has no benefit over a non-virtual function. This is just a short sample snippet to demonstrate the feature.

Additionally, as described in other answers, this actually breaks function hiding -- you won't ever be able to have an `f` function with the same parameter list in `D` or any of its derived classes.
This is a trade-off to be done when you decide to cap `f` in your model. Since there is no way to perform an actual virtual call here, you essentially have the disadvantage and no benefit.

Comment: I thought of name hiding. Thus you prevent the derived class to hide f(). If you declare f() without virtual keyword, it can be hidden in derived class I guess.

Comment: Comments are, as always, much appreciated with downvotes.

Comment: I think the downvotes are due to your attitude towards disabling name hiding. I suppose this feature can actually be used for some special purpose, although I can't name any such purpose off the top of my head.

Comment: @Ruslan well, anything to do with static polymorphism for a start. I don't know, disabling arbitrary features because you don't know a use for them and claiming it's for the better sounds very short-sighted to me. Is there a `goto`-like taboo on function hiding that I'd have missed?

Comment: By the feature I don't mean "function name hiding" — I mean "disabling function name hiding". Of course I do know uses for name hiding itself.

Comment: @Ruslan oh, my bad :)