# Why is constructor of a grand parent deleted in this case?

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance

The compiler is complaining the constructor of D is deleted because of ill forming why ?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class A
{
   int x;
   public:
   A(int i) { x = i; }
   void print() { cout << x; }
};

class B: virtual public A
{
   public:
      B():A(10) { }
};

class C: virtual public A 
{
   public:
      C():A(10) { }
};

class D: public B, public C {
};

int main()
{
   D d;
   d.print();
   return 0;
}
```

**Output**

> main.cpp:37:4: error: use of deleted function 'D::D()'   D d;
>       ^ main.cpp:32:7: note: 'D::D()' is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:  class D: public B, public C {
>          ^

Comment: Because there's no default constructor available for `D` to initialize those base classes.

Comment: Because A does not have a default constructor.

Comment: Because of virtual inheritance `D` must call ctor of `A` directly and there is no default one there

Comment: Not direct dupe but could be helpfull https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17184514/final-class-implementation-in-c

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Due to the rules for initialization of virtual base classes,

```
class D: public B, public C {
};
```

is equivalent to:

```
class D: public B, public C {
    public:
       D() : A(), B(), C() {}
};
```

That's why you cannot create in instance of `D`.

**Solution 1**

Change `A` so it has a default constructor.

```
class A
{
     int x;
   public:
     A(int i = 0) { x = i; }
     void print() { cout << x; }
};
```

**Solution 2**

Change `D` to:

```
class D: public B, public C {
    public:
       D() : A(0), B(), C() {}
};
```

or a simpler version,

```
class D: public B, public C {
    public:
       D() : A(0) {}
};
```

Comment: I do not think it is necessary to call default ctors of `B` and `C` explicitly

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/9908015/1489510 comment section, TL;DR: A's constructor is not being called thrice

Answer (score 2):

That's because `D` inherits from `A` indirectly using `virtual`. A doesn't have a parameterless constructor so a compiler-generated constructor for `D` can't be made.

Answer (score 0):

Note: this is mostly just adding a reference to the standard, in case anybody might care (but as usual for him, @R. Sahu's answer is quite accurate).

The standard specifies ([class.base.init]/13) that:

> In a non-delegating constructor, initialization proceeds in the
>   following order:
> (13.1) — First, and only for the constructor of the
>   most derived class (6.6.2), virtual base classes are initialized in
>   the order they appear on a depth-first left-to-right traversal of the
>   directed acyclic graph of base classes, where “left-to-right” is the
>   order of appearance of the base classes in the derived class
>   base-specifier-list.
> (13.2) — Then, direct base classes are
>   initialized in declaration order as they appear in the
>   base-specifier-list (regardless of the order of the mem-initializers).

So, since `A` is a virtual base class, it's initialized directly by the most derived class (`D`). Only afterward, the direct base classes are initialized--but for anything to compile, the most derived class must be able to initialize the virtual base class(es).

There is one point some might find interesting in a case like this. Let's modify your class structure just a tiny bit, so we to the necessary initialization, and (importantly) initialize with a unique value in each constructor:

```
#include <iostream>

class A {
    int i;
 public:
    A(int i) : i(i) {}

    void show() { std::cout << "value: " << i << "\n"; }
};

class B : virtual public A{
public:
    B() : A(10) {}
};

class C : virtual public A { 
public:
    C() : A(20) {}
};

class D : public B, public C {
public:
    D() : A(0) {}
};

int main() {
    D d;
    d.show();
}
```

In this case, what exactly happens? We have three different constructors each "thinking" it's going to initialize the `A` object with a different value? Which one "wins"?

The answer is that the one in the most-derived constructor (D::D) is the one that' used to initialize the virtual base class object, so that's the one that "wins". When we run the code above, it should print `0`.