# A function from a base class is being hidden in the subclass. How do I fix this?

Tags: c++, inheritance

In the base class, I have a function `GetDetections` which takes a string filename, constructs a feature set, and defers its work to a pure virtual function `GetDetections`.

In the subclass, I implement this virtual function.

In `main`, I have an instance of the subclass, and call `GetDetections` with a filename. I thought this would call the base class's non-virtual function that accepts a string argument, but this does not compile. The error is:

> prog.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
>
> prog.cpp:33:48: error: no matching function for call to ‘SubClass::GetDetections(const char [13])’
>
> prog.cpp:33:48: note: candidate is:
>
> prog.cpp:26:9: note: virtual int SubClass::GetDetections(const std::vector&) const
>   prog.cpp:26:9: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘const char [13]’ to ‘const std::vector&’

Here is the code. (Also posted at http://ideone.com/85Afyx)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

struct Feature {
  float x;
  float y;
  float value;
};

class BaseClass {
  public:
    int GetDetections(const std::string& filename) const {
        // Normally, I'd read in features from a file, but for this online
        // example, I'll just construct an feature set manually.
        std::vector<Feature> features;
        return GetDetections(features);
    };
    // Pure virtual function.
    virtual int GetDetections(const std::vector<Feature>& features) const = 0;
};

class SubClass : public BaseClass {
  public:
    // Giving the pure virtual function an implementation in this class.
    int GetDetections(const std::vector<Feature>& features) const {
        return 7;
    }
};

int main() {
    SubClass s;
    std::cout << s.GetDetections("testfile.txt");
}
```

I've tried:

- Declaring `GetDetections` in the subclass as `int GetDetections`, `virtual int GetDetections`.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1628768/why-does-an-overridden-function-in-the-derived-class-hide-other-overloads-of-the, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/411103/function-with-same-name-but-different-signature-in-derived-class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The implementation of the virtual function inside derived class with hide the overloaded `GetDirections` function in base class.

try this:

```
using BaseClass::GetDetections;
int GetDetections(const std::vector<Feature>& features) const {
    return 7;
}
```

for SubClass

Comment: That worked (http://ideone.com/rEW7Dt) Thank you! However, this seems cumbersome. Is this the standard way to do this?

Comment: @Sancho I think so. There should be another way, but I just cannot remember for now.

Comment: Yes, a using declaration like this is the best way to unhide members.

Answer (score 0):

Overloaded virtual functions are hidden. However you can call the `BaseClasse`'s `GetDetections` with its qualified name as

```
std::cout << s.BaseClass::GetDetections("testfile.txt");
```