# Override pure virtual function from derived template class

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

Does anyone knows why this code cannot be compiled in visual studio 2013? The problem lies in this that b.a() has only one version (the overrided one in B class a(float)) and version a(std::string) is unavailable although it is in base class.

```
#include <string>

template <typename T>
class A { 
public:
    virtual void a(std::string b){ this->a(123); }
    virtual void a(float b) = 0;
};

class B : public A < std::string > {
public:
    virtual void a(float b) override {}
};


main()
{
    B b;

    b.a(""); // Error here: error C2664: 
             // 'void B::a(float)' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'const char [1]' to 'float'

    B* bb = new B();
    bb->a(""); // same
}
```

Comment: `static_cast<A&>(b).a("");` :-)

Comment: static_cast<A<std::string>&>(b).a(""); this one works but it's a bit too much code ;) Thank you for answer anyway :)

Comment: I was mainly trying to get you to think about why you want a polymorphic hierarchy but address objects through their concrete interface rather than their abstract base.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/411103/function-with-same-name-but-different-signature-in-derived-class

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If a derived class declares a name and you also want members of this name from base classes to be visible, you need to unhide those names explicitly, using `using`:

```
class B : public A<std::string>
{
public:
    using A<std::string>::a;
    virtual void a(float b) override {}
};
```

Now you can use all overloads of `a`:

```
B x;
x.a(1.2);
x.a("hello");
```

Comment: Da*n, u'r good! I'm a bit confused coz i met this problem first time although i write in C++ from some time... So if derived class override a function for ex. fun1 then all functions called fun1 from base class are automatically hidden in derived class (except overrided one)?