# Can I change accessors from the default inheritance?

Tags: c++, inheritance, accessor

I understand that public/protected members are protected by protected inheritance, and they are private by private inheritance. But can I change them to public explicitly (as shown below)? I actually don't quite understand what it means by "public: A::x"....

```
    class A
{
public:
    int x;
    int y;
protected:
    int z;
};

class B : protected A   
{
public:
    A::x;
};

class C : private B 
{
public:
    B::y;
    B::z;
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class B : protected A   
{
public:
    A::x;
};
```

This is not a valid syntax any more. This `access declarator` is deprecated now. To change accessibility of inherited member, you should use `using` keyword

```
class B : protected A   
{
public:
    using A::x;
};
```

Now, although `x` was inherited as protected, you explicitly chnged this to `public` access. So this is possible now:

```
B b;
b.x = 0; //Ok
b.y = 0; //Error, cannot access protected member
```

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
A::x;
```

is an "access declarator", so it indeed allows you to "make" an inherited member visible in the `public` area of the derived class. It is also used to make visible [hidden overloaded functions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/411103/3093378). However it is now deprecated in C++, so try using

```
using A::x;
```

Example:

```
#include <iostream>

class Foo
{
protected:
    int x{10};
};

class Bar : public Foo
{
public:
    using Foo::x; // makes x "public" here
};

int main()
{
   Bar bar;
   std::cout << bar.x << std::endl;
}
```