# Strange behaviour when calling virtual functions

Tags: c++, virtual

I don't understand what is wrong with this code. It looks like an incredible trap !

This code :

```
class Foo
{
  public:
      virtual double foo(double x) const = 0;
              double foo(int x) const { return (double)(x + x); }
};

class Bar : public Foo
{
    public:
        virtual double foo(double x) const { return x * x; }
};

int main()
{
    Bar* b = new Bar;
    Foo* f = b;
    std::cout << b->foo(3) << " " << f->foo(3) << std::endl;
    std::cout << b->foo(5.0) << " " << f->foo(5.0) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

prints the following output :

```
9 6
25 25
```

I deduce that `Bar::foo(double) const` is called with an implicit cast when the type of the pointer is `Bar*`. But **why such a thing is possible without any warning ?**

I work with GCC 4.7.2. I compiled with `g++ -Wall foobar.cpp -o foobar.exe`

Comment: I think it would be better if you choose your second number another than 2. Because 2*2=4 and 2+2=4.

Comment: I'm curious, do you have the same issue if the return value of `foo(int)` is also `int`? @nabroyan indeed, it would be even better to use the same value (but different type): `3` and `3.0`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1628768/why-does-an-overridden-function-in-the-derived-class-hide-other-overloads-of-the and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/411103/function-with-same-name-but-different-signature-in-derived-class

Comment: You're right. I changed with `5.0`.

Comment: @Kryptos: yes, same behaviour.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is due to name hiding.

When you declare a function called `foo` in `Bar`, you hide all declarations with the same name in `Foo`.

As such, when the static type of the pointer is `Bar`, the compiler *only* finds the version in `Bar` which takes a `double`, so it implicitly converts the `int` to satisfy this.

If you want the `int` version in `Foo` to be visible, add a `using` declaration:

```
class Bar : public Foo
{
    public:
        using Foo::foo;
//      ^^ makes the versions in Foo visible
        virtual double foo(double x) const { return x * x; }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

When the type is `Bar*`, only one version of the method is visible, the one with the `double` parameter.

**Base methods with the same name (but different signature) are hidden.**

To make them available, you can use `using Foo::foo` in the derived class.

Depending on your compiler, I think you might also get warnings regarding the implicit conversion, or the fact that you apparently want to call a hidden method.

Answer (score 1):

In `Foo` there are two overloads of `foo`, one that takes a `double` and another that takes an `int`.

In `Bar` there is one overload of `foo`, the one that takes a `double`. This overload hides all functions with the same name from the base classes. This is called *name hiding*.

A fix would be to employ *using declaration* to bring the other `foo` overloads from the base class in scope of `Foo` derived class:

```
class Bar : public Foo
{
    public:
        using Foo::foo; 
        virtual double foo(double x) const { return x * x; }
};
```