# Detect std::size_t type at compilation time to call the right function

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor, preprocessor, size-t, boost-preprocessor

Managing my own archive system, I have the following virtual functions:

```
virtual void OutputArchive::save_unsigned_long_int(unsigned long int i);
virtual void OuptutArchive::save_unsigned_long_long_int(unsigned long long int i);
virtual void InputArchive::load_unsigned_long_int(unsigned long int& i);
virtual void InputArchive::load_unsigned_long_long_int(unsigned long long int& i);
```

Then, for some reason I also have to manage type `std::size_t`, which can be different depending on the compiler. For example, with gcc on Linux 64-bits, `std::size_t` is a `unsigned long int`, but with intel on Windows 64-bits, `std::size_t` is a `unsigned long long int`. In a first approach, I wrote something like that:

```
void OutputArchive::save_size_t(std::size_t i)
{
  if(boost::is_same<std::size_t,unsigned long int>::value)
    this->save_unsigned_long_int((unsigned long int)i);
  else if(boost::is_same<std::size_t,unsigned long long int>::value)
    this->save_unsigned_long_long_int((unsigned long long int)i);
  else { /* error management */ }
}
```

But, I'm not happy with that: it's ugly, only one line can ever be executed, the type is known at compilation time. I suppose it's possible to do better with preprocessing, but I don't know how to start this. Any help is welcome.

*Note: I don't use C++11 for compatibility reason, but I use Boost.*

Comment: Rather looks like a use case for SFINAE.

Comment: `std::size_t` is always a type alias, is it not? You don't need to add an overload for it if it's covered by one of those two.

Comment: `save_unsigned_long_int` and `save_unsigned_long_long_int`? Doesn't that rather bypass the entire *reason* for C++ having overloads? Why is this not *one* function name allowing for multiple types in the arguments?

Comment: @StoryTeller: but I don't know which function to call when I have to save a `std::size_t` without testing the type. It's why I centralize this with this function.

Comment: @paxdiablo : because the functions are virtual.

Comment: Then consider paxdiablo's comment. Overloading is a good thing. And it doesn't at all preclude virtualizing them.

Comment: You might want to pass your variables by `const` reference to obviate unwanted type conversions.

Comment: Seriously, your point about not overloading because they are virtual makes no sense. [The two are not mutually exclusive](https://ideone.com/oUV6Zv).

Comment: @StoryTeller, actually, since [this bug](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30751499/3378179), we decided to not mix overloading and virtuality in our codes.

Comment: @Caduchon - I'm sorry to tell you, but this is a daft decision. Cutting off your nose to spite your face. Yes, name hiding is a problem, but it's still useful to overload an interface.

Comment: @StoryTeller: `override` is C++11. I don't use it.

Comment: @Caduchon - Who said anything about `override`? ;)

Comment: @StoryTeller: your example. ;-)

Comment: @Caduchon: that's a bad decision of yours. Anyway, if you insist on it, then add a non-virtual overloaded wrapper function into the base class, which calls the virtual one.

Comment: @Caduchon - That would still work without the specifier. I just use it as a force of habit.

Comment: Declare a `save()` template method. Specialize it for each data type to call the appropriate virtual method. The End.

Comment: Consider explicitly using one of the bigger uintxx_t (instead of size_t or unsigned long [long] int)

Comment: Overloading is a good thing. (you've read that twice now)  Overload and override are different things.

Comment: -3 for this question ? Honestly ? Stackoverflow becomes a kind of sect where you have to know every little detail about the standart to have the right to post a question ? One of the downvoters can explain me why "This question does not show ANY research effort; it is UNCLEAR or not USEFUL" ? My God, protect guys working physically with them...

Answer (score 1):

The preprocessor knows nothing about types. Or scopes. Or anything which involves the semantics of the program. All the preprocessor can deal with are tokens, which are just sequences of characters corresponding to a small set of lexical rules.

In short, it is true that the type is known at compile-time, but not during the translation phases corresponding to the preprocessor. C++ uses type information at compile-time  to determine the appropriate overloaded function, and to deduce the correct template definition. Either of those could be an appropriate solution to your problem.

It's possibly worth noting that the C++ standard only requires that `size_t` be "an unsigned integer type". It does not need to be a *standard unsigned integer type* (see §3.9.1p1), so it is possible that `size_t` is neither `unsigned int`, `unsigned long int` nor `unsigned long long int`. (A similar comment applies to `ptrdiff_t` and signed integer types.)