# Changing signature while Overriding in C++

Tags: c++, default-value, overriding, method-signature

I have a base class

```
class Shape{
    public:
        virtual int getArea()=0;
}
```

I want to change the signature while `overriding` like this:

```
class Rectangle : class Shape{
    public:
        int getArea(int someParameter = 0){
            return 0;
        }
}
```

Is it possible somehow to achieve this, as I am using default value for newly added parameter?

Comment: If you change signature you are no longer overriding, you are overloading. And no, it's no longer possible to use polymorphism as `Shape::getArea` and `Rectangle::getArea` are two different functions.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: I understand that, but is there any way out?

Comment: @Abhinav : This is not possible. you can get some come information here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/411103/function-with-same-name-but-different-signature-in-derived-class

Comment: You could probably get away by defining a separate hierarchy of "AreaParameter", declaring the virtual taking a pointer or a reference to such parameter (`virtual int getArea(const AreaParameter &p = AreaParameter())`), doing a real override in the subclass and in there downcast the parameter type. (Or in general by employing any double dispatch technique...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only solution I can see is that you implement both `int getArea()` *and* `int getArea(int)`, where one function can call the other (for example `int getArea() { return getArea(0); }`). You can not have the overload taking an argument have a default argument then.

Answer (score 0):

You need to overload your virtual function. But if you overloaded virtual function, you will get a warning "hides overloaded virtual function"

Solution is override function with native signature and overload it with virtual prefix.

Example:

```cpp
class A {
   virtual void foo(int) {...}
};

class B: public A {
   void foo(int i) override {
       A::foo(i);
   }
   
   virtual void foo(const std::string& str) {
       ...
   }
};
```