# Member functions of a derived class

Tags: c++, inheritance

When a class is derived from a base class, will the member functions of the base class become member function of the derived class. That is, for example if I write:

```
class A 
{ 
public : void f();
};
class B : public A 
{ 
public : void f1();
};
```

Now if the question is to name the member functions in class B, then will f() also become a member function of class B ?

Comment: If it has same signature then it will hide base member function. You'll access though a reference to `B` then you'll get `B::f()` otherwise `A::f()`. See also: http://stackoverflow.com/q/411103/1207195

Comment: In this case there are no the same signatures. You can call `f()` on object of `class B`. That's why people created inheritance

Comment: There are no keywords `Public` or `Class` in c++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> then will f() also become a member function of class B ?

No. `f()` is still a member function of class `A`, class `B` just inherits it. In your case it's a public member function and public inherit, means you can call `f()` on a `B` object.

```
B b;
b.f();
```

On the other hand, class `B` can define own member function `f()`:

```
class A 
{ 
public : void f();
};
class B : public A 
{ 
public : void f(); // will hide A::f()
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, class `B` has two functions: `f1()` and `f()`.

If `f()` was `protected` in `A`, too, but `f()` could only be used from within the member functions of `A` and `B` (and from `friend`s).

And if `f()` was `private`, `B` would have only one function `f1()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
class A { 
public : void f();
};
class B : public A 
{ 
public : void f1();
};
```

Now code is valid.
It is visible. Even when you change f1 name to f it is still visible in B class. If you wanna use it use scope operator ::.

Like this:

```
A::f()
```

More about basic inheritence
http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/112-basic-inheritance-in-c/